# Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?

Tags: c#, sql-server, tipagem

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto para automação comercial, utilizando PAF-ECF e tudo o mais.

Aual seria o melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com SQL Server e C# para questões de dinheiro? Principalmente em relação a arredondamentos e truncamentos.

Imagino que as melhores opções sejam `Float`, `Numeric` ou `Money`. Mas não consigo encontrar boas fontes confiáveis que se adaptam ao meu caso para que eu possa implementar com segurança.

Comment: Decimal é o campo fácil de trabalhar.
O *Microsoftmente* correto é:
**money**
e **smallmoney** [http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179882.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179882.aspx)

Comment: Decimal com certeza.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Amigo, deixo aqui um pouco da minha experiência, trabalho com sistemas de automação comercial utilizando o Microsoft SQL Server, e sugiro fortemente que utilize campos monetários com tipo `DECIMAL`.

Na empresa em que trabalho já chegamos a utilizar números de ponto flutuante para dinheiro, mas no entanto tivemos problemas sérios após os valores serem processados muitas vezes, principalmente por módulos como os de Nota Fiscal Eletrônica, e pior ainda, de SPED contábil e fiscal.

Com o tipo DECIMAL passamos a ter muito mais controle e precisão sobre os valores armazenados.

Sugiro estas duas leituras para maiores detalhes.

- [Tipos de dados: FLOAT / DOUBLE vs DECIMAL](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913200455/http://douglascunha.com/blog/2010/08/tipos-sql-float-double-decimal/)
- [.Net - Float(Single), Double e Decimal. Afinal qual devo usar?](http://www.macoratti.net/12/12/c_num1.htm)

Comment: Apenas complementando a resposta. Em alguns casos, os números de ponto flutuante podem ser "do mal". A explicação da razão: [Por que números de ponto flutuante &#40;Float e Double&#41; são imprecisos?](http://ericlemes.com/2013/08/12/float/)

Comment: qual configuração de decimal vc recomenda? digo tamanho

Answer (score 36):

Decimal. Nunca use tipos com ponto flutuante (`float`, `single`, `double`, etc). 
Uma outra alternativa conhecida é armazenar os valores em centavos, como `int`'s ou `long`'s. Ou seja, ao invés de armazenar 12,34 (reais) você armazenaria 1234 (centavos).  Isso só é viável se você trabalhar só com uma moeda pois o número de casas decimais varia de moeda para moeda.

Editado: Em SQL Server eu recomendo `Money` e em C# `decimal`.

A propósito, há uma lista boa [nessa página da MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: É um facto que vírgula flutuante binária (como `float`) é um erro para trabalhar com dinheiro. No entanto, a pergunta também pergunta `numeric` vs `money` e esta resposta não explica porque motivo evitar o "money".

Comment: Veja esta questão de SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server

Answer (score 27):

Utilize **`Decimal`**, pois este tipo irá representar valores descritivos (isto é, **valores exatos**). Valores monetários e quantidades absolutas são exemplos deste caso;

Os tipos de ponto flutuante (ex: **`float`**) servem para representação de valores contínuos (isto é, valores que representam uma **aproximação**, ou que "tendem a"). Exemplos da "vida real" seriam: peso, distância, altura, etc.

Note que, embora sua balança te diga que você pese 80 Kg (digamos), provavelmente seu peso real será uma **aproximação** disso (79,899875499 ....). Nestes casos os tipos de ponto flutuante caem bem. Já com dinheiro, não será legal...

Conceito retirado [deste vídeo proferido pelo Jon Skeet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3nPJ-yK-LU#t=536).

Answer (score 21):

**Nunca use tipos ponto flutuante** tal como float ou double. A representação desses valores segue o padrão [IEEE_754](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) e foram projetados exclusivamente para aplicações científicas. Aplicações financeiras exigem precisão absoluta pois em em um sistema de contabilidade, por exemplo, não pode ser tolerado nenhuma diferença num saldo, mesmo que seja de poucos centavos em Bilhões de Reais, pois causa desconfiança que causaria no sistema (dando a impressão de existencia de erro).

Assim você deve usar sempre aritimética decimal provida pelos tipos DECIMAL, BigDecimal, etc. Existe um *erro implicito* quando usamos aritimética binária e convertemos para aritimética decimal (aquela que aprendemos na escola) que ocorre devido a diferença de bases dos dois sistemas de numeração.

Answer (score 13):

Recentemente conclui um aplicativo PAF-ECF, do início ao fim, e não tenho nenhum problema com ele. Utilizei Money no banco de dados (SQL Server), e no sistema de gestão e no PAF-ECF (ambos em C#) utilizei Decimal. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente.
Para o caso de sistemas de gestão e PAF-ECF, de modo enfático não recomendo a separação dos centavos, o que torna o tratamento muito mais difícil, tanto no SGBD quanto nos aplicativos.
Resumindo, na minha opinião, utilize Money no SGBD e Decimal no C#.

Answer (score 13):

Como recomendado por Martin Fowler em seu livro [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) você deve utilizar:

1. Um tipo inteiro com a quantia (1000 = R$ 10,00)
2. O tipo da moeda (Reais ou Dólares ).

Você deve evitar utilizar qualquer tipo de ponto flutuante pois isso poderá causar problemas de arredondamento que é o que você quer evitar.
Nos cálculos você deve sempre levar em conta o tipo da moeda.

Answer (score -5):

Sugiro esse código para isso:

```
public class MOEDA
    {
        public int umavez = 0;

        public string Calcular(string valor1, string valor2, int operacao)
        {
            string saida = "";

            int total = 0;

            int val1, val2;

            valor1 = valor1.Replace("$", ""); valor2 = valor2.Replace("$", "");
            valor1 = valor1.Replace(".", ""); valor1 = valor1.Replace(",", "");
            valor2 = valor2.Replace(".", ""); valor2 = valor2.Replace(",", "");
            valor1 = valor1.Trim(); valor2 = valor2.Trim();

            int.TryParse(valor1, out val1); int.TryParse(valor2, out val2);

            int calcular = 0;

            if (operacao == 1) { calcular = 1; }
            if (operacao == 2) { calcular = 2; }
            if (operacao <= 0) { calcular = 3; }
            if (operacao == 4) { calcular = 4; }
            if (operacao == 5) { calcular = 5; }

            switch (calcular)
            {
                case 1://soma
                    total = val1 + val2;
                    break;
                case 2://multiplicar
                    val2 *= operacao;

                    total = val1 + val2;
                    break;

                case 3://subtrair
                    if (val1 == val2)
                    {
                        total = val1 - val2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (val1 > val2)
                        {
                            total = val1 - val2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (val1 < val2)
                            {
                                total = val2 - val1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case 4://porcentagem

                    float porcentagem = ((float)val2 / 100) * val1;
                    total = val1 + (int)porcentagem;

                    break;
                case 5://divisao
                    float v = (float)val1 / (float)val2;
                    total = (int)v;

                    break;
            }
            saida = total.ToString();

            saida = FormataMoeda(saida);

            return saida;
        }

        string FormataMoeda(string corpo)
        {
            string set = corpo.Replace("$ ", "");

            if (set.Length < 22)
            {
                set = set.Replace("$ ", "");

                set = set.Replace(".", "");

                set = set.Replace(",", "");

                switch (set.Length)
                {

                    case 3:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 1) + "," + set.Substring(1, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 2) + "," + set.Substring(2, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 3) + "," + set.Substring(3, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 1) + "." + set.Substring(1, 3) + "," + set.Substring(4, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 2) + "." + set.Substring(2, 3) + "," + set.Substring(5, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 3) + "." + set.Substring(3, 3) + "," + set.Substring(6, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 9:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 1) + "." + set.Substring(1, 3) + "." + set.Substring(4, 3) + "," + set.Substring(7, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 10:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 2) + "." + set.Substring(2, 3) + "." + set.Substring(5, 3) + "," + set.Substring(8, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 11:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 3) + "." + set.Substring(3, 3) + "." + set.Substring(6, 3) + "," + set.Substring(9, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 12:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 1) + "." + set.Substring(1, 3) + "." + set.Substring(4, 3) + "," + set.Substring(7, 3) + "," + set.Substring(10, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 13:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 2) + "." + set.Substring(2, 3) + "." + set.Substring(5, 3) + "." + set.Substring(8, 3) + "," + set.Substring(11, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    case 14:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 3) + "." + set.Substring(3, 3) + "." + set.Substring(6, 3) + "." + set.Substring(9, 3) + "," + set.Substring(12, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;

                    ///-------------------------------------- Não reconhece 15 caracteres
                    case 15:
                        set = "$ " + set.Substring(0, 1) + "." + set.Substring(1, 3) + "." + set.Substring(4, 3) + "." + set.Substring(7, 3) + "." + set.Substring(10, 3) + "," + set.Substring(13, 2);
                        umavez = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }
            //-------------------------------------- Não reconhece 15 caracteres
            //-------------------------------------- Não reconhece 15 caracteres

            return set;
        }
        //---------------------------------------
        //---------------------------------------

    }
```

Comment: USO:  Moeda calcular = new Moeda();

Comment: string Total = calcular.Calcular("$ 100,00","$ 20,00",1);

Comment: Não acho que um código que tem uma sopa de `switch`es, que tem um monte de números mágicos, que usa uma flag mágica e que foi desenvolvido com bastante copiar-e-colar seja a melhor forma de modelar-se uma classe de moeda.