# Formatar decimal com virgula e milhar com ponto

Tags: c++, qt

Como posso formatar um `float` para o formato brasileiro de valor(preço)?

Exemplo: em php `number_format($float,2,',','.')` separa o decimal com virgula e a unidade de  milhar com ponto.

Comment: Você quer dizer: utilizar o ponto como separador de milhar? (não tem muito sentido utiliza-lo como separador de dezena)

Comment: Ponto por 3 dezena(unidade). No tópico informa.

Comment: Pelo que me lembro da matemática 3 dezenas = 30. Não vejo sentido e não sei o significado de "Ponto por 3 dezena(unidade)" (o que unidade significa neste contexto?).

Comment: 3 dezenas multiplicadas é equivalente a um milhar. Essa é a convenção de nomenclatura mais utilizada (em inglês seria "*thousands separator*"). Editei a pergunta para usar essa convenção, se isso estiver incorreto é só reverter a edição.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Esta correto! Uma unidade de milhar ou (unidade).

Answer (score 12):

## Usar QLocale

Se a formatação que pretendes é utilizada em determinada língua, podes formatar o teu número definindo o [Qlocate](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qlocale.html#enumSection) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> com a língua que contém a formatação pretendida:

```
// a definição actual em uso
QLocale loc = QLocale::system();

// Recolher a formatação de números utilizada para a língua Portuguesa
QLocale brasil(QLocale::Portuguese);
loc.setNumberOptions(brasil.numberOptions());

// Define como valor por defeito
QLocale::setDefault(loc);
```

A partir daqui a formatação de números já deverá estar conforme é utilizado pela língua Portuguesa.

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado.

Comment: Estou tendo outro problema. Os valores estão sendo arredondado. Exemplo `11.020,51` mostra `11.020,50`. Você sabe como posso somar os valores sem arredondar?

Comment: @user628298 O melhor é tentar trabalhar com valores em formato de `inteiro` e não `float`. Conforme foi perguntado aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5746/melhor-tipo-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-dinheiro

Comment: @Lucas Nunes Vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado.

Comment: @user628298 Podes fazer uso das funções nativas de c++ `ceil()` ou `floor()`. Podes também utilizar `QString::number(sum, 'f', 1)`. Ver esta [documentação](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#argument-formats) e [esta](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number).

Answer (score 6):

A solução utilizando a biblioteca padrão C++, fica assim:

Primeiro é necessário criar uma especialização da classe std::numpunct e sobrescrever dois métodos afim de implementar o comportamento específico para nossa moeda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

class BRL : public numpunct<char>
{
    protected:

    //separador de milhar
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const
    {
        return ',';
    }

    //padrão de agrupamento dos milhares, de 3 em 3
    virtual std::string do_grouping() const
    {
        return "\03";
    }
};
```

Então para utilizar faz-se o seguinte:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    float _valor = 1022.33;

    //instanciando um locale que utilizará a especialização de numpunct
    locale br(locale(), new BRL());

    //configurar no cout o locale que será utilizado nas formatações
    cout.imbue(br);

    //setprecistion() é necessário para configurar precisão de apenas duas casas decimais
    //fixed é necessário para que o valor não seja impresso como notação científica.
    cout << "R$ " << setprecision(2) << fixed <<  _valor;

    return 0;
}
```

A saída no console fica assim:

```
R$ 1,022.33
```

Versão completa no [ideone](http://ideone.com/bhZy3U).

Comment: Complementando: Você pode olhar mais opções sobre como mudar os parâmetros (de virgula para ponto ou como preferir) na documentação da classe: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct