# Como formatar valores monetários com C++?

Tags: c++, formatação, números

Gostaria de apresentar valores formatados como moeda, com separadores de milhares e centavos.

Gostaria que, por exemplo, `56000/12` apresentasse `4.666,67`. Eu consigo apresentar `4,666.67`. Teria algum jeito de trocar o `.` (ponto) pela `,` (virgula)?

*Se quiserem, esse é o código que uso (as 11 primeiras entradas são de 5000 e a 12º é de 1000):*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

class BRL : public numpunct<char>
{
    protected:

    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const
    {
        return ',';
    }

    virtual std::string do_grouping() const
    {
        return "\03";
    }
};

int menor5000;
float stop,media,mes,tot,var;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    cout <<"\n\t\tExercício 5\n";
    locale br(locale(), new BRL());
    cout.imbue(br);

    for (menor5000,mes=1,stop=0;stop<12;stop++,mes++)
    {
        cout<<"Digite o valor da venda no " << mes <<"º mês: ";
        cin>>var;
        if (var < 5000)
        menor5000++;
        tot = tot + var;
    }

media = tot / 12;
cout<<"\n\nA media de vendas mensais em 2013 é de R$ " << setiosflags (ios::fixed) << setprecision(2) << media << "\n";
cout << "\nForam realizadas " << menor5000 << " vendas menores que R$ 5,000.00.";

return 0;
system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Isto te responde? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9810/formatar-decimal-com-virgula-e-milhar-com-ponto

Answer (score 5):

Ora, você praticamente tem a resposta você mesmo. Basta modificar a classe que herda de [`numpunct<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct). Implemente o `do_decimal_point` para retornar uma vírgula e faça o `do_thousands_sep` retornar um ponto. Aqui um exemplo:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class CurrencyLocale : public numpunct<char> {
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const   { return '.'; }
    virtual char do_decimal_point() const   { return ','; }
    virtual std::string do_grouping() const { return "\03"; }
};

int main() {
    locale currency(locale(), new CurrencyLocale());
    cout.imbue(currency);

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << 5654214.54 << endl;
}
```

Resultado é:

```
5.654.214,54
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe um método chamado [`Replace()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/), você pode trabalhar ele em conjunto com o [`Find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). Segue um pequeno exemplo de como utilizar:

Alterei para responder ao **Maniero**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  using namespace std;

  string str;

  str = "5,000.00";

  str.replace(str.find(','),1,"@");
  str.replace(str.find('.'),1,",");
  str.replace(str.find('@'),1,".");

  cout << ("%s",str);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, eu vi como muda o ponto para a vírgula. E como você vai mudar vírgula para o ponto?

Comment: [edit]e sua reposta para colocar o exemplo.

Comment: Está na resposta o exemplo.

Comment: Não precisa do crédito não. Até porque você alterou para a resposta não ficar errada. Do jeito que estava, resultava em "5,000,00".

Comment: Levei como base a pergunta: **eu consigo apresentar 4,666.67 teria algum jeito de trocar o . (ponto) pela , (virgula)?**. Obrigado pela observação @bigown

Comment: É, a pergunta estava mal feita, é normal quando o OP não entende exatamente o problema que ele está tentando resolver, aí a gente tem que tentar suprir esta deficiência.

Comment: -1. Isso não vai funcionar com valores que possuam mais de um separador decimal, como `1,000,000.00`. A solução está em manipular o locale para gerar o valor já no formato certo, em vez de mudar depois. Além disso, o que você pensa que `cout << ("%s",str);` faz? O literal antes da vírgula é ignorado completamente.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Se a solução é manipular o locale, a pergunta é duplicata da que o bigown linkou lá em cima?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não havia lido o comentário dele. Bom... ele parece querer o formato americano e não o brasileiro como na pergunta, mas a ideia é exatamente a mesma, mudando só alguns parâmetros como mencionei na resposta. Acho que dá para considerar duplicata sim.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Ou talvez não, porque com qt a resposta mais votada lá parece mais simples (não sei C++ para julgar direito). E aqui a pergunta é sem qt.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal ainda tinha esquecido deste detalhe. Eu já não tinha gostado da solução :)