# Como faço no c++ para imprimir um número milhar separado por ponto com o printf

Tags: c++, printf

Estou precisando saber se tem como eu exibir um número milhar com um ponto utilizando por exemplo o printf no C++.

Exemplo de código:

```
int main(){
    int exemplo = 1500;
    printf("Seu número é = %d", exemplo);
    return 0; 
}
```

Dessa maneira ele retorna **1500**, preciso formatar para que seja exibido **1.500**.

Quem puder ajudar desde já agradeço.

Comment: Olá Vinyipa, você pode usar o [`std::ios_base::imbue`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/imbue/) + locale, ou pode separar o numero em chars e com um loop for decrementando uma variavel a partir do 0 (de trás pra frente) checar qual se é a quarta operação (pode usar o %). **[EDITADO]**: encontrei uma resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9838/3635, apesar da pergunta ser sobre Qt a sugestão do Fábio é C++ puro e é fácil de adaptar a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com [`std::numpunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct) você pode configurar as casas decimais usando [`do_decimal_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/decimal_point), controlar o separador de milhar com [`do_thousands_sep`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep) (os grupos de milhar podem ser ajustados usando o método [`do_grouping`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/grouping)).

Uma outra [resposta aqui no site mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9838/3635) já sugeri como usar para formatar moedas, no caso como aqui só deseja colocar a virgula nos milhares então bastará usar `thousands_sep` e `do_grouping`,

Exemplo de implementação:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;
 
struct thousand_formater : numpunct<char>
{
    // separa milhar com pontos
    char do_thousands_sep() const { return '.';  }

    // grupos de 3 digitos
    string do_grouping() const { return "\03"; }
};
```

Então se desejar exibir apenas você pode setar no [`std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::imbue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) para trocar o *locale* em `std::cout`:

```
cout.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), new thousand_formater));

cout << 110 << endl;
cout << 1500 << endl;
cout << 13200 << endl;
cout << 500000 << endl;
cout << 99999999 << endl;
```

Se desejar/precisar salvar o valor formatado em uma string, você pode usar:

```
stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(locale(cout.getloc(), new thousand_formater));
ss << 89898989;

string resultado = ss.str();

cout << resultado << endl;
```

Exemplo no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/Ug8jXN)

Comment: Deu certo dessa forma amigo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score -4):

Eu sugiro que você use **float** no lugar de **int** e utilize **cout** no lugar de **printf**

float x = 1.500;
std::cout << x;

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    float exemplo = 1.500f;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << x;
    return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Mas aí vc está imprimindo o número "um e meio", e a pergunta pede pra imprimir o número "mil e quinhentos". Tudo bem que nesse caso específico o resultado é "o mesmo", mas formatar um float com determinada quantidade de casas decimais e um int com separador de milhares são duas coisas completamente diferentes