# Casas decimais do float

Tags: java, float, valor-monetário

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para controlar vendas de produtos. Porém, às vezes o valor somado dos relatórios não batem as casas decimais. Dá pequenas diferenças. Como fazer para que o `float` pare de dar estes problemas? Sempre uso somente duas casas decimais no `float` e às vezes ele coloca mais sozinho. Gostaria de uma forma que o `float` ficasse somente com duas casas decimais e nos relatórios de venda sempre calculasse correto. É possível?

Comment: Relacionado: [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/3117) (em C#)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Com o `float` não há o que fazer. Essencialmente já respondi: [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101) tem vários links para outras informações, recomendo ler todos, principalmente os que estão em inglês, se puder. Este parece ser um dos problemas mais comuns encontrados em programadores novatos (e até experientes).

`float` não pode ser usado para trabalhar com dinheiro, ele não tem precisão e não é porque falta casas decimais, poderia ter 30 milhões de casas decimais e ainda teria problemas. A dificuldade é a forma como ele é calculado e representado. Ele é muito rápido por ser binário mas não consegue representar todos os números possíveis, então o número que você quer armazenar possivelmente será representado por outro número bem próximo do que você quer. Isto não é problema na maioria dos cálculos científicos mas é impraticável para dinheiro.

O `float` pode ser mostrado com duas casas decimais mas ele sempre tem várias casas em sua representação. E novamente, não é isto que causa o problema.

E não adianta usar `double`. Nem mesmo um *superdouble*, ou *halffloat* se existissem. Provavelmente só vai criar mais problema.

O correto é o uso do [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) que é a solução mais simples e costuma ser muito eficiente. Ou ainda alguma biblioteca para tratar especificamente de [Money](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money) ou a [API oficial para dinheiro](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html) que é um pouco inferior (parece que vem uma [nova API no Java 9](https://javamoney.github.io/), não sei se resolve o problema). Cuidado, essas bibliotecas podem ser exageradas para o que você precisa. Estes tipos trabalham com [exatidão decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_data_type), ou seja, eles conseguem representar qualquer número sem erro.

Ex.: `BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123.45");`

De qualquer forma é necessário cuidado, [essas classes não resolvem todos os problemas sozinhas](http://www.guj.com.br/java/285650-trabalhar-com-valores-monetarios-em-java#1509593).

A *string* é usada para evitar problemas de arredondamento já que o Java não possui uma literal para tipos decimais.

[Saiba mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado. Vou estudar o Decimal.

Comment: O link para a "nova API no Java 9" está quebrado.

Comment: @Piovezan botei um outro

Answer (score 14):

Como respondido acima, o uso de Decimal normalmente resolve seu problema de uso de ponto flutuante em Java.

Gostaria apenas de compartilhar uma técnica que aprendi na década de 80 trabalhando com linguagens que não tinham esse tipo de dado: multiplique os valores monetários por 100 e converta-os para inteiro. Faça as somas e subtrações necessárias e no final divida o resultado por 100.

Como na prática você trabalhou o tempo todo com inteiros, não deverá ocorrer diferenças...

Comment: Exato, funciona também. Na outra resposta que eu apontei eu falo isso.