# Qual a cardinalidade entre uma solicitação e os serviços inclusos nela?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, uml, cardinalidade

Tenho a classe `Solicitacao` e a classe `Servicos`. Após  a inserção no banco de dados pretendo recuperar em uma consulta todos os serviços associados aquela solicitação.

Por exemplo, em uma tela eu faço a inserção da solicitação e de vários serviços. Quando chegar a hora de fazer a consulta quero trazer a solicitação e assim que clicar em um botão aparecer um Dialogo com todos os serviços dessa solicitação.

Esse relacionamento seria `1-N` ou `N-N`?

Meu diagrama:
[image: UML]

Comment: se seu serviço só pode ter uma solicitação então seria 1-N ( uma solicitações para vários serviços).

Comment: Tipo, esse serviço só vale pra essa solicitação na hora desse cadastro?
Por exemplo se eu iniciar um segundo cadastro e usar o mesmo serviço cadastrado no primeiro continuaria sendo 1-n?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depende do que são esses serviços.

Se os serviços são específicos para esta solicitação, ou seja, são linhas de itens que a solicitação deve ter, então é `1-N`. Para cada solicitação você tem vários serviços. Mas um serviço só pode estar em uma solicitação.

Mas se os serviços são genéricos e são cadastrados na solicitação de forma direta, então você tem um relacionamento `N-M` (`N-N` significaria que a relação deveria ter um número de itens simétrico). Você tem uma solicitação que é composta de vários serviços. Cada serviço pode estar em quantas solicitações forem necessárias.

Então pela descrição é a segunda forma. Mas em geral isto é *design* ruim. O certo seria ter uma tabela de `Itens de solicitação` em relação `1-N`. E cada item ter uma relação com `Serviços` de `N-1`. Ou seja, cada item de solicitação tem um serviço relacionado, mas cada serviço pode estar em qualquer quantidade de itens de solicitação.

Com a edição da pergunta e colocação do diagrama, parece que a tabela `Servico` funciona como um item de solicitação, então seria `1-N`. O nome dá indicação errada do que a tabela é. A coluna `codigo` também está esquisita. É o código deste serviço? E como vincula com a solicitação? Se isto é o código da solicitação, tem um vínculo, mas aí teria que ser `1-1` já que não seria possível ter uma chave primária de outra forma.

Modelagem depende muito da situação específica. Tem algumas ideias básicas para se seguir mas sem entender completamente o problema é difícil falar alguma coisa. E pelo que vejo uma das maiores dificuldades dos desenvolvedores é entender completamente o problema. Quando escapa um detalhe e modela errado pagará lá na frente. Eu ainda erro muito, mesmo com mais de 35 anos de experiência. Mas faço um esforço grande para acertar porque isto é mais importante que a maioria das outras habilidades do nosso trabalho. Entender o problema errado certamente produzirá a solução errada e nem sempre fica óbvio até ser tarde demais e ser muito mais difícil arrumar o problema.

Mais um detalhe: você está usando `double` para valores monetários, [isto é terrível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101), veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). O uso de `long` para os códigos não me parece adequado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, no meu caso que tenho uma tela de cadastro aonde faço a inclusão da solicitação junto com o serviço essa opção de criar a tabela `Itens de solicitação` é válida?

Comment: Leia minha edição, veja se dá para entender os problemas que você está enfrentando. Como você não domina as nomenclaturas, fica difícil entender o que você quer. Enquanto não dominar essas coisas, você terá dificuldade de modelar. Mas eu acho que que você deveria ter essa tabela que eu disse e o serviço ser um entidade separada. Se você quer fazer que o serviço seja só uma informação jogada na solicitação, aí não precisa desta outra tabela mas ainda teria problemas na forma como você montou.

Comment: O código é auto incremento, mas acho que já entendi mais ou menos. É minha primeira modelagem depois de algum tempo, tenho que treinar rsrs

Comment: @bigown, apenas tirando uma dúvida recomenda String, int ou integer para os códigos?

Comment: Coloquei double nos valores pois não achei BigDecimal no `Astah`, e o que eu uso para o código?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino aí é outra pergunta :D Se funciona como um ID eu vou de `int` em quase todas situações. Se for um código de uso dos usuários, depende de como ele pode ser formado. Em muitos casos eu iria de `string` mas este tipo de código caiu em desuso em aplicações modernas, eu evitaria. Hoje códigos costumam ser irrelevantes em muitas situações. Se o controle do número tiver que ser independente do ID do DB, aí você terá alguma rotina que o gerará de acordo com a necessidade. Fica melhor `string` ou `int`? Não sei, depende da situação, mas eu diria que tem chance maior de ser `string`.

Comment: @bigown, hahaha, despertou mais dúvidas, vou gerar uma pergunta mais especifica, obrigado pelo comentário!

Comment: O problema maior é que eu sou u único desenvolvedor da empresa kk e mal acabei a faculdade. Vou ir fazendo os diagramas da forma mais simples de começo assim conforme o ganho de conhecimento posso melhorar esses diagramas. Obrigado por ajudar.

Comment: E vai perguntando aqui se tiver problemas específicos e bem definidos.