# Converter String para Float com virgula em Java

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo

Como faço para converter de uma forma elegante `String` pra `float` em java?

As strings estão com a localização brasileira, isto é, os valores vêm com vírgula como separador decimal ("12,345").

Acho tão... "feio" usar

```
        String preco = request.getParameter("preco");
        try {                
            cadastro.setPreco(Float.valueOf(preco.replace(",", ".")));                
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            cadastro.setPreco(0);
        }
```

Não dá pra acreditar que o java não tenha alguma localização...existe alguma maneira?

Comment: É feio mesmo capturar `Exception` . Feio e perigoso. Capture apenas as exceções que você espera.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101

Comment: Como faz falta um `tryParse` em java...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma das maneiras que conheço é utilizando [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numero = "199";
    System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(Float.parseFloat(numero)));
}
```

> Iprime: R$ 199,00

---

Atualizado

Para receber números com vírgulas pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public static double converte(String arg) throws ParseException{
    //obtem um NumberFormat para o Locale default (BR)
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
    //converte um número com vírgulas ex: 2,56 para double
    double number = nf.parse(arg).doubleValue();
    return number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String numero = "199,99";
    BigDecimal bg = new BigDecimal(converte(numero)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(bg);
}
```

Editei a resposta e fiz uma conversão do valor para `BigDecimal`, que é o formato mais recomendado para se trabalhar com moedas. Futuramente você pode refatorar seu código e trabalhar diretamente com o `BigDecimal`.  Esse método `converte` pode ser um método de uma [Classe Utilitária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90047/principal-objetivo-de-classes-utilit%C3%A1rias).

Veja funcionando no Ideone: https://ideone.com/cZ73CB

Comment: e se colocar uma virgula nessa string?

Comment: @DiegoF Editei a resposta :p

Comment: A linha `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();` deve ser `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR");`. Não assuma que sua VM será em pt-br por omissão.

Comment: Muito obrigado @josivan, adicionei na resposta :p

Comment: Corretíssimo @josivan. **Sempre** defina o *locale*. Um bom programa é *locale-aware* e todas as rotinas devem definir o Locale para evitar comportamentos inesperados, incluindo operações relacionadas a data, número e texto como `toLowerCase`.  Sempre consulte o Javadoc da API e prefira os métodos com Locale.