# Problema com centavos ao usar o tipo BigInteger

Tags: java, valor-monetário

Estou tendo um problema para somar centavos.
Informo 1200, retorna 1.200,00 em vez de 12,00.

Código:

```
formatar_data(1200);

private int formatar_data(int inteiro){     
    BigInteger  valor = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(inteiro));  
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale( "pt", "BR" )); 
    String formatado = nf.format (valor);
    System.out.println(formatado);
    return inteiro;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usar `double` ou `float` para representar dinheiro é pedir para ter problemas e causar prejuízos. Esses são tipos com a parte fracionária binária e não pode representar todos os valores possíveis.

Esses tipos são ótimos onde a exatidão não é necessária. O que não é o caso de dinheiro.

Uma das técnicas mais comuns para representar valores monetários é utilizar inteiros. Ou seja, cada unidade equivale a **um centavo**. Quando precisa a parte fracionária, divide-se pelo resultado de 10 elevado ao número de casas decimais que precisa.

É comum as linguagens oferecerem um tipo próprio para isso tratando corretamente as casas decimais como decimais. Em Java este tipo é o [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (infelizmente não existe um tipo mais curto, esse gasta "muita" memória).

Outra possibilidade é o uso do [Joda Money](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money). Pode ser exagero para muitos casos. Uma variação dela parece estar sendo considerada para inclusão no Java padrão.

Isso já foi respondido [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40048/101) e aconselho ler e seguir os *links* para maiores detalhes.

Eu repensaria toda aplicação e decidiria agora com mais subsídios como pretende trabalhar com valores monetários. Apesar dos inteiros serem interessantes, nem todo mundo quer lidar com os detalhes dele e prefere um tipo que faça isto pelo programador.

Se continuar com inteiros precisará mudar tudo o que tem para lidar com os centavos. Além disso entenda que número é diferente de representação textual do número. Com números você faz contas, mas quando apresenta números no fundo está lidando com textos, portando dados formatados são sempre textos:

```
private String formatar_data(int inteiro, int casas) { //mudei o tipo do retorno
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale( "pt", "BR" )); 
    String formatado = nf.format(inteiro / (Math.pow(10, casas)));
    System.out.println(formatado); //imagino que isto é só para testar
    return formatado; //eu eliminaria esta variável
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/FormatDate.java).

Como há quem negue o uso de inteiros vai alguns *links*:

- [Martin Flower](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html) ([Outro](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html))
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)
- [Tutorial Java](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13)
- Existem livros que não consigo por um *link* aqui. Cito o livro Effective Java:

  > The right way to solve this problem is to use BigDecimal, **int** or **long** for monetary calculations.

Diversas linguagens não possuem um tipo que manipule dinheiro de forma abstrata e o uso do inteiro é a única opção. Isso é usado há anos sem problemas em software que rodam por décadas.

O tal do `BigDecimal` é só uma abstração para o uso de um inteiro e isto dá alguma facilidade. Ele dá algumas facilidades mas tira alguma flexibilidade e poder. Com abstração ou sem políticas de cálculo, arredondamento, escala e outras transformações devem ser usadas sob discrição do programador. Em certas circunstâncias, uma política pode ser abstraída em algum tipo específico, mas não um tipo geral como o `BigDecimal`.

Um detalhe que poucas pessoas sabem que é pode até usar `float` ou `double` para representar dinheiro e coisas semelhantes. Desde que garanta que só usará números inteiros, afinal os inteiros podem ser representados com precisão nestes tipos. Claro que o programador teria que garantir isto, então faz pouco sentido fazer isto, mas fica a título de curiosidade, não de recomendação, pelo contrário.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo, para mim era um absurdo tratar moeda como inteiro. Agora tudo faz mais sentido.

Comment: É um absurdo tratar moeda _de verdade_ como inteiro, veja a minha resposta. Para _guardar_, _apresentar_ ou _preservar_ números de precisão finita `float`s e `doubles`s não são apropriados, mas isso não implica que a melhor resposta sejam inteiros. Tem tipos em memória e em banco de dados específicos de números de precisão finita. Eles que devem ser utilizados.

Comment: @AndréLFSBacci anguns dos maiores entendidos no assunto discordam de você. De qualquer forma eu não disse o que é melhor, eu disse que é uma situação melhor que `float`. Mas estou longe de dizer que isto é um absurdo. Isso sim seria um absurdo. Diversos softwares são feitos assim por gente competentíssima há muito tempo. O fato de você não gostar da solução, não significa que ela não seja eficaz. Você pode escolher o que quiser para você mas não imponha o seu gosto para todo mundo.

Answer (score 8):

Para continuar usando o mesmo tipo, você pode multiplicar todos os valores por 100. Como centavos não variam na quantidade de casas decimal, é fácil de manter todos os seus dados consistentes e ao usar um tipo inteiro, você consegue melhor precisão em todas as contas.

Quando for exibir para o usuário, você vai precisar dividir por 100  todos os valores, claro.

Comment: +1. E além de tudo, ganha performance no processamento e eficiência na armazenagem. Pra ficar fácil de gerenciar, quando se trata da base de dados, usamos aqui a nomenclatura valor100, desconto100, quantidade1000 nos campos, assim fica claro o fator de divisão.

Answer (score 6):

### Resposta ao problema

Pelo que entendi, queres formatar um "inteiro que internamente tem duas decimais" como um valor monetário. Mexeu com dinheiro, a resposta necessariamente passa por BigDecimal.

```
private static String formataPtBr(int inteiro)
{
    BigDecimal hundred = BigDecimal.TEN.pow(2);
    BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(inteiro).divide(hundred);
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt",
            "BR"));
    String formatado = nf.format(value);
    // System.out.println(formatado);
    return formatado;
}
```

Seis coisas:

1. Tem como fazer de outras formas, com `int`, `string`? Tem, mas daí isso te abre problemas inesperados de arredondamento e trucamento. Vai funcionar em 99,99999% dos casos, mas com 99,99999% de certeza vai lhe custar noites inteiras mal dormidas, caçando esses [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). Nenhuma das soluções apresentadas menciona `fpstrict`, portanto há zero garantia de que o resultado que você vê na sua máquina é o que será calculado em outra.
2. Nome: formata_data? Melhor algo bem mais especifico, camelCase: `formataBrl()`, `formataPtBr()` ou algo assim. Condiz mais com o conteúdo da função.
3. Usar um tipo primitivo para uma coisa bem específica e diferente do original é um [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Talvez ache um *overkill* criar um tipo específico para número, mas se estiver fazendo um sistema grande e a sério, essa é uma decisão que você **vai** se arrepender.
4. Relacionado à anterior, você estar fazendo `x = formata_data(valor)` em vez de `x = valor.formataPtBr(2)`. Outro sinal que as coisas estão mal estruturadas.
5. Ter um tipo específico vai te forçar a usar o sempre tipo correto *e isso é bom*. Vai evitar de passar o inteiro sem querer num lugar que aceite inteiro, na hora de debugar você sempre vai ver o resultado formatado correto, sem malabarismos mentais.
6. Se estiver preocupado com performance, crie *singletons* de `hundred` e `nf`. Onde colocar? Mais uma razão para criar uma classe específica para esse tipo dinheiro que é um "inteiro com duas casas decimais".

BigDecimal está pronto, é padrão, bem testado e cobre todos os pontos acima.

### Inteiro para moedas *virtuais*

Existe uma situação qual o uso de inteiro para moedas é aceitável. O caso de *moedas virtuais*, de mentirinha mesmo. Estou falando aqui de pontuações, dinheiro de jogos digitais, coisas assim. Nesse tipo de contexto, onde rola muito [fracionamento não decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimalisation) isso pode ser interessante.

Por exemplo, num mundo virtual onde a menor denominação é cobre, que equivale a 100 pratas, que por sua vez equivalem a 100 ouros, é interessante guardar o saldo de dinheiro na menor denominação (o cobre), pois isso facilita todas as contas. Só na hora de exibir que, daí sim, faz se a separação dos fatores de uma forma "para humanos", deixando a forma inteiro para a máquina lidar.

Fora desse contexto **é uma péssima ideia**.

### Decimal para moedas *reais*

Porque inteiro é boa ideia para moedas de mentirinha, e uma péssima ideia para moedas de verdade? Em poucas palavras: [divisão](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29), [multiplicação](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.multiply%28java.math.BigDecimal%29), [exponenciação](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.pow%28int%29), [raiz quadrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649703/square-root-of-bigdecimal-in-java), [arredondamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Moedas de mentirinha geralmente só operam somas, subtrações, multiplicações. Moedas de verdade rapidamente são envoltas em operações *financeiras*, que envolvem matemática mais elevada, que *exigem* decimais *extras, parciais* para funcionar corretamente. Coisa que é impossível num tipo "sem escala", como é o caso de usar inteiro fixo com duas casas decimais.

E essas são as operações mais "simples". E se está com dificuldade de colocar decimais na representação, não parece que vai sequer acertar esses outro algoritmos. Performance, então, esquece.

Pegar uma coisa simples, arredondar. Tem [trocentos tipos de arredondamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding), todos diferentes entre si, e que existem porque são necessários em certos tipos de fórmula. Um tipo inteiro com duas decimais *nem tem o que arredondar* para além das duas casas decimais, de onde se tira que um tipo assim sequer vai funcionar nessas fórmulas.

---

Então, a sério. Se está mexendo com dinheiro de verdade, use BigDecimal.

Se não quiser usar BigDecimal, pelo menos crie um tipo "MyMoney", para diferenciar esse caso de outros, e pendure métodos apropriados nele, em vez de funções soltas no código.

Comment: Embora sua resposta esteja correta me dá vontade de negativar por dizer que a solução passa por necessariamente usar `BigDecimal`. Isto não é verdade. Esta é apenas uma das soluções. O fato de você se limitar nas soluções não significa que isto seja correto. Você pode fazer a escolha que quiser, mas não imponha a sua solução para outras pessoas quando existem alternativas. Na verdade o inteiro não tem os problemas que você está falando. Ou até tem, os mesmos problemas do `BigDecimal`.Se não souber lidar com a escala corretamente,vai ter problemas com os dois.Não cabe aqui uma resposta completa

Answer (score 4):

[`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) e [`Intenger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) (`int`) são tipos de dados usados para trabalhar com **números inteiros**. Os tipos [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) e [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) são mais recomendados para trabalhar com números decimais.

Porém, se estiver trabalhando com moedas e precisar usar inteiros por causa da precisão, você deverá trocar o retorno do seu método `formatar_data` de `int` para `String`. Ficaria algo como:

```
private String formatar_data(int inteiro){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); // Formato com 2 casas decimais
    return df.format(inteiro/100.0);
}
```

Comment: Ouvir falar que para  Representar uma moeda é melhor usar inteiros. Outra  o banco de dados esta retornando tudo inteiro.

Comment: Para representar uma moeda é melhor usar inteiros? Onde você "ouviu" falar isso?

Comment: É impossível formatar um inteiro com casas decimais, ou você usa o tipo de dado correto ou você vai ter que trabalhar com strings no meio do processo.

Comment: @Hy-brazil Veja como ficaria retornando `String`.

Comment: Sobre onde "ouviu". No livro Martin Fowler em seu livro Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture  e  Bloch também defende o uso de inteiros no livro Effective Java.

Comment: @Hy-brazil Eu entendi o que você quis dizer. Perceba que eu editei a minha resposta, isso deve lhe atender. Você não conseguir "formatar" uma variável `int` com casas decimais, vai ser necessário usar `String`.

Comment: @jbueno ok, obrigado.