# Converter diagrama MER (Modelo Entidade Relacionamento) para classes VB.NET ou C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, modelagem, der

Desenvolvi o diagrama das tabelas do layout do XML de NFe, são 58 tabelas com seus relacionamentos. Gostaria de gerar as classes automaticamente a partir do diagrama ou pode ser através do banco de dados também. Existe alguma ferramenta para isso?

[image: DER]

Comment: Aproveitando a sequência de "é isso" do Paulo Henrique, você está usando DOUBLE pra valores monetários, é isso? Espero que seja só um exercício de faculdade, ou coisa do tipo. Apesar de não ser a mesma linguagem, entenda os problemas aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118418/70

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que tal [usar o Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generate-code-from-uml-class-diagrams?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mesmo? Até porque parece ter sido feito nele. Eu sei que ele gera para C#. Não sei sobre VB.NET, embora tenha como converter. Me parece que esse recurso não está disponível em todas edições do VS.

[É possível fazer no Microsoft Visio](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/design-and-generate-code-with-visio/219200253).

Se tiver que fazer em outro software vai dar tanto trabalho que escrever o código na mão será mais vantajoso. Alguns softwares conseguem ler o diagrama criada no VS. É o caso do [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/visual-studio-uml-to-csharp-tutorial.jsp).

Tem o [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/) que é *open souce*, ou o [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), ou o [Modelio](https://www.modelio.org/).

Ainda tem o [UModel](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html) e o [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html).

É claro que de pouco adianta gerar o código se o diagrama tiver erros cruciais. Conforme o Bacco até disse em comentário eu espero que isso seja um exercício e nada fiscal de fato. Se bem que depois de tanto trabalho, mesmo sendo um exercício, ter um erro grave não é legal. Se for pra uso fiscal é gravíssimo.

[Não pode usar `double` para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101). Isso causa enormes prejuízos para as empresas, inclusive multas. É preciso muita responsabilidade para programar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).