# Uso correto do Override e construtor

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Me foi solicitado que fosse criada uma classe conta corrente que tivesse um atributo que representasse a taxa cobrada por cada transação de dois atributos da superclasse (crédito / débito).

E foi pedido pra subscrever os métodos de crédito e débito para descontar o valor da taxa a cada transação bem sucedida.

Fiz o código dessa forma:

```
public class ContaCorrente extends Conta {

    protected float taxa;

    public ContaCorrente(float saldoconta) {
        super(saldoconta);
    }   

    public void atualiza(float taxa){
        this.saldoconta = this.saldoconta - taxa;
    }

    @Override
    public void mostracredito(float valor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.mostracredito(valor);
        this.saldoconta = this.saldoconta - this.taxa;
        System.out.println("Saldo da conta com desconto da taxa"+ this.saldoconta);
    }

    @Override
    public void mostradebito(float valor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.mostradebito(valor);
        this.saldoconta = this.saldoconta - this.taxa;
    }   
}
```

Assim está certo? Ou devo alterar mais alguma coisa? Para todas as classes, foi solicitado o construtor, foi isso que me complicou.

Essa é a classe `Conta`:

```
public class Conta {
    //ATRIBUTOS
    protected float saldoconta;

    //CONSTRUTOR
    public Conta(float saldoconta) {

        this.saldoconta = saldoconta;
    }

    //METODOS PUBLICOS
    public void mostrasaldo(){
        System.out.println("O saldo na conta é :" +this.getSaldoconta());
    }
    public void mostracredito(float valor){
        this.saldoconta = this.saldoconta + valor;
    }
    public void mostradebito(float valor){
        this.saldoconta = this.saldoconta - valor; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi bem. Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você fez e quer apenas saber se está correto?
Não acho legal esse tipo de pergunta, você quer que a gente analise seu código, se você estivesse com algum problema tudo bem mas analisar algo que você fez é meio tenso.

Comment: Eu acho que estou errando na forma de colocar o metodo de desconto no saldo .

Comment: O que você quer dizer com: `colocar o metodo de desconto no saldo`?

Comment: Quero saber se  @Override é dessa forma que usa . por que nas aulas a professora não passava super classes com construtor . então fiquei meio perdido nisso

Comment: Foi solicitado que no debito e credito fosse realizado o desconto ( utilizando o atributo taxa ) , porém estou em duvida se o código esta correto .

Comment: @FelipeLamarao O código faz o que é pedido no exercício?

Comment: @FelipeLamarao A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Se eu entendi certo, se o enunciado está correto, exceto pelo fato de [usar `float` para valor monetário que é um erro conceitual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118407/101) que calculará valores errados, mas que não atrapalha um exercício, e que você só pode subscrever (usando a terminologia postada que eu acho que foi errada) um método se ele for um evento ([padrão Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101)), você pode sobrescrever o método, parece tudo correto. Talvez o `super` deveria ser chamado depois de calcular o saldo, mas não tenho como saber se é o desejado, só estou especulando.

O [`@Override`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/101) está correto.

Note que o construtor não precisa porque no fundo ele é estático, nem poderia ser diferente já que a instância não existe ainda, é ele que a criará. Sendo estático, não há polimorfismo e não tem que sobrescrever.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, o termo correto é **sobre**screver, e não **sub**screver.

Você tem um método `mostracredito` e um `mostradebito`. Esses métodos na subclasse, não apenas mostram o crédito ou débito, mas também o alteram, e portanto eles não fazem o que o nome do método diz fazer. Já na superclasse, esses métodos não mostram nada, embora seja isso o que o nome indique.

Assim sendo, a sua implementação não é a adequada, pois o nome de um método deve inidicar o que ele faz.

Além disso, em uma conta corrente, as operações disponibilizadas devem ser a de efetuar um crédito ou um débito, e não a de mostar um crédito ou um débito. O comportamento de mostrar neste caso é um intruso, ele não faz parte daquilo que o método deveria fazer. Tanto é que no enunciado do exercício te foi pedido para  sobrescrever os métodos de crédito e débito para descontar o valor da taxa a cada transação bem sucedida, e isso não significa mostrar nada.

E também, respeite [as regras de nomenclatura do Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132), ainda mais que isso é um exercício no qual você será avaliado por um professor.

E se você está em uma classe chamada `Conta`, e você tem um atributo chamado `saldo`, este só pode ser o saldo da conta. Portanto, chamar o atributo de `saldoconta` é redundante, `saldo` é suficiente. O mesmo pode ser dito do método `getSaldoconta` - chamar de `getSaldo` é suficiente.

O fato de você deixar o atributo como `protected` dá às subclasses o poder de alterá-lo da forma como elas bem quiserem sem que a superclasse supervisione ou interfira em nada. Entretanto, com esse poder também vem uma responsabilidade: as subclasses passam a ter a responsabilidade de gerenciar esse atributo de forma adequada. Porém, se a superclasse já disponibiliza métodos para creditar e debitar valores no saldo, então a superclasse já tomou para si a responsabilidade de controlar esse saldo, logo isso não é algo que deveria ser repassado às subclasses, que ao acessar o saldo diretamente, estariam então violando as regras estabelecidas nos métodos da superclasse para manipular o saldo. Com isso conclui-se que o atributo do saldo deveria ser privado.

Poderíamos levar em conta o ponto abordado [na resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209447/132), o tipo ideal para o saldo seria o [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Na sua subclasse `ContaCorrente`, o método `atualiza` recebe como parâmetro uma taxa, mas a própria classe já tem uma taxa como atributo. Uma vez que esse método não usa o valor do parâmetro para atualizar o atributo, logo existem duas taxas diferentes aqui. Isso é um erro de modelagem na sua classe. De fato, do jeito que a sua subclasse está modelada, a taxa que está no atributo será sempre zero.

O nome `atualiza` é um nome bem vago e genérico para uma operação. O nome `taxar()` é mais preciso. Além disso, se é responsabilidade da subclasse `ContaCorrente` descontar o valor da taxa para cada transação bem sucedida realizada na conta e ela é a classe que disponibiliza quais são as operações a serem realizadas nessa conta, logo não faz sentido que outras classes saiam descontando a taxa a seu bel-prazer, pois essa é uma responsabilidade que já foi tomada integralmente pela classe `ContaCorrente`. Assim sendo, provavelmente não faz sentido que o método `taxar()` seja público, e portanto é melhor que ele fique privado.

Eu faria a sua superclasse assim:

```
public class Conta {

    private BigDecimal saldo;

    public Conta(BigDecimal saldo) {
        if (saldo == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public void mostrarSaldo() {
        System.out.println("O saldo na conta é: " + this.getSaldo().toPlainString());
    }

    public BigDecimal getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void creditar(BigDecimal valor) {
        if (valor == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.saldo = saldo.add(valor);
    }

    public void debitar(BigDecimal valor) {
        if (valor == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.saldo = saldo.subtract(valor);
    }
}
```

Sua subclasse ficaria assim:

```
public class ContaCorrente extends Conta {

    private BigDecimal taxa;

    public ContaCorrente(BigDecimal saldo, BigDecimal taxa) {
        super(saldo);
        if (taxa == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.taxa = taxa;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTaxa() {
        return taxa;
    }

    public void setTaxa(BigDecimal taxa) {
        if (taxa == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.taxa = taxa;
    }

    private void taxar() {
        super.debitar(taxa);
    }

    @Override
    public void creditar(BigDecimal valor) {
        super.creditar(valor);
        taxar();
    }

    @Override
    public void debitar(BigDecimal valor) {
        super.debitar(valor);
        taxar();
    }
}
```

Ah, note que os métodos nunca aceitam saldo, taxa ou valores a creditar ou debitar que sejam nulos. Rejeitar valores nulos é em geral boa prática de programação (mas não é algo que possa ser sempre aplicado).

Algumas regrinhas sobre sobrescritas de métodos:

- Em geral, qualquer método pode ser sobrescrito, exceto os que:

  (a) forem estáticos, ou

  (b) tiverem o modificador `final`, ou

  (c) sejam privados ou

  (d) estejam em uma classe `final`.
- A anotação `@Override` pode ser adicionada a métodos que sejam sobrescrita de métodos da superclasse. A finalidade dela é forçar um erro de compilação caso o método em questão não seja uma sobrescrita. Em especial, isso é útil para que o compilador reclame quando a superclasse sofrer uma alteração que vá quebrar a subclasse, o que é muito melhor do que o compilador aceitar silenciosamente um código onde as subclasses estão quebradas.
- O ideal é que todos os métodos que fossem sobrescritas tivessem uso do `@Override` obrigatório. Entretanto, o uso dele é opcional por uma questão de retrocompatibilidade com versões do Java 1.4 e anteriores que não possuiam essa anotação.
- Quando o método da superclasse é chamado com uma instância da subclasse, e essa subclasse sobrescreve o método, o método invocado será o sobrescrito na subclasse, não o método base da superclasse.
- Uma subclasse pode acessar os métodos que ela sobrescreveu da superclasse ao usar a referência `super`. Por exemplo para invocar o método `x()` da superclasse, tendo ele sido sobrescrito na subclasse, deve-se usar `super.x()`.
- Note que apenas a subclasse pode acessar os métodos originais da superclasse que ela sobrescreveu. Eles não poderão ser acessados diretamente por outras classes que estiverem tentando utilizá-los por meio de uma referência à subclasse.
- A partir do Java 8, interfaces podem ter métodos concretos com o modificador `default`. Se uma classe `X` herdar duas ou mais implementações concretas de um mesmo método `abc`, seja por meio da superclasse ou por meio de interfaces (por exemplo, interfaces `Y` e `Z`), ela poderá acessá-los por meio da sintaxe `Y.super.x()` ou `Z.super.x()`.
- Se uma subclasse define um método com o mesmo nome de um método privado da superclasse, isso não será uma sobrescrita. Será apenas um método diferente com o mesmo nome. O uso da anotação `@Override` neste caso será um erro de compilação.

Algumas regrinhas sobre os construtores com subclasses:

- Para que o construtor da subclasse invoque o construtor da superclasse, deve haver uma chamada `super(...)` logo no início do construtor da subclasse.
- Os parâmetros dessa chamada `super(...)` são os parâmetros do construtor da superclasse.
- Se a superclasse tiver um construtor sem parâmetros (mesmo que seja o construtor implícito adicionado pelo compilador quando nenhum construtor é declarado), então esse será o construtor invocado se você não tiver uma chamada `super(...)` no início do construtor da subclasse. Nesse caso, o compilador colocará uma chamada implícita a `super();` lá.
- É possível que um construtor invoque um outro construtor da mesma classe ao usar uma chamada do tipo `this(...)` ao invés de `super(...)` no início do construtor. Novamente, os parâmetros dessa chamada são os parâmetros do construtor em questão.
- Se a superclasse não tiver um construtor sem parâmetros, então o construtor da subclasse será obrigado a invocar algum dos construtores da superclasse com o `super(...)` ou um outro construtor da mesma classe com o `this(...)`.
- Cuidado com o caso de construtores de uma mesma classe estarem chamando o `this(...)` ciclicamente. Se o construtor *A* chama o construtor *B* e o construtor *B* chama o construtor *A*, você vai ter um `StackOverflowError` se tentar instanciar essa classe.
- Construtores podem ter qualquer tipo de visibilidade, incluindo `private`.
- Não é possível fazer sobrescrita de construtores. Na sobrescrita de um método, quando o método da superclasse é invocado com uma instância da subclasse, o método invocado é o da subclasse. Já no construtor, você sempre invoca o nome da subclasse com o `new`. Tal como o Maniero disse na resposta dele, a instância nem existe ainda nesse caso para que ocorra a seleção de alguma implementação. No caso de construtores, ao invés de sobrescrita, temos encadeamento, vez que todos o construtor da subclasse sempre deve chamar o construtor da superclasse.

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado !! de verdade . ainda estou aprendendo ,mas vou continuar estudando muito para melhorar cada vez mais

Comment: @FelipeLamarao Se esta resposta solucionou o seu problema, clique no ✅ que está ao lado do começo dela para marcar esta resposta como aceita e a sua pergunta como solucionada. Se achar que a resposta do bigown é melhor, marque a dele. Se isso ainda não esclareceu completamente a sua dúvida, poste alguns comentários e vamos esclaarecer. De qualquer forma, é sempre um prazer ajudar.