# "OMG! Um heisenbug!" - Explicando a um leigo o que é um heisenbug

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

Um *Heisenbug* é um bug que muda seu comportamento ao ser estudado [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). Ele tem seu nome derivado devido ao princípio que Heisenberg detectou que a simples "observação passiva"<sup>*</sup> de processos quânticos alteram o resultado final.

Heisenbugs típicos acontecem com [condições de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/64969), pois qualquer tipo de medição que você faça (como *trace debugging* ou *break points*) acaba por sincronizar os processos concorrentes de uma forma ou de outra. O [@André LFS Bacci](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/41731/andr%c3%a9-lfs-bacci) indicou que usar ponto flutuante para fins monetários podem causar heisenbugs [[2]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118633/64969).

<sup>*: Na física quântica não existem observações puramente passivas, mas isso são detalhes</sup>

---

Então, imaginem que estou numa situação complicada tentando resolver um problema no sistema e até consigo reproduzir o bug, mas quando eu tento ver mais coisas sobre o bug colocando um *break point* estratégico, esse bug deixa de acontecer. Nesse momento, me deparo com aquela situação:

> "OMG! Um heisenbug!"

O [PHB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss) me pergunta o que está acontecendo. O suporte está com o cliente na linha. Preciso dar uma resposta sobre como está o andamento do estudo desse problema, preciso pedir mais tempo para tentar sanar porque não é um bug simples, mas um heisenbug!

Como consigo explicar para o chefe e para o suporte sobre o heisenbug? Eles não são os mais profundos conhecedores da programação, acham que só por um `if (stuff_will_bug()) { dont_do_stuff(); } else { do_stuff(); }` resolve o problema magicamente.

<sup>*: De preferência, explicações que não resultem na minha demissão</sup>

Comment: cara, agora paro de chamar esses bugs de bug mágico. Eu curti muito :D

Comment: @TiagoTiede, tem toda uma classificação de "bugs quânticos". Na verdade o que sofrem mais onde trabalho é com mandelbugs/bugs fractais, que para corrigir um bug você tem de corrigir 3 bugs (e assim recursivamente até o infinito). Vale a pena dar uma lida nas referências que eu pus na questão

Comment: Me interessei sobre o assunto. Vou ler mais. Valeu pela dica.

Comment: Downvoter, poderia me ajudara melhorar esta questão?

Comment: Não sou o downvoter, mas acho que o problema da sua pergunta é que o que você está perguntando é "*Como consigo explicar para o chefe [PHB] e para o suporte sobre o heisenbug?*" - Isso daí tende a ser uma pergunta mais opinativa do que objetiva. Além disso, existe uma lei do universo (acabei de inventá-la) que diz: "***Todo aquele que se aventure a tentar explicar conceitos complexos para olhos e ouvidos de idiotas, só terá dor, miséria e sofrimento como resultado.***"

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu entenderia essa questão da possibilidade de resultar em uma resposta opinativa/subjetiva *se* viesse acompanhado de um voto de fechamento por esse motivo. Btw, adorei essa máxima universal.

Comment: Oxi, meu próximo label no GitHub vai ser **"gafanhoto do inferno"** quando perguntarem o que é posto o link do "heisenbug". Agora sério. Como explicar algo há alguém que nitidamente não tem capacidade de entender? Acredito que a abordagem deva ser levar ao superior (mesmo que seja um "ignorante") a questão para traçar metas padrão para analise e discutir a abordagem (padrão) ao se lidar com o cliente. Em uma equipe de trabalho a definição monocrática não é a melhor forma de tratar o tema.

Comment: @LauroMoraes o foco não deveria ser que fosse algo além da capacidade técnica das outras pessoas, mas sim que eles são leigos, que teriam dificuldade numa explicação puramente técnica, sem "amaciar" o conteúdo antes

Comment: @VictorStafusa, *"Todo aquele que se aventure a tentar explicar conceitos complexos para olhos e ouvidos de idiotas, só terá dor, miséria e sofrimento como resultado"* isso seria uma boa resposta se não gerasse conflito com uma afirmação da pergunta: *" De preferência, explicações que não resultem na minha demissão"*  :-D

Comment: O problema parece ser de paralelismo e processamento assíncrono, correto? Então você já tem ideia do que está acontecendo, só não sabe como resolver o problema. Qual é o real problema? Concorrência de processos? Alocação de recursos? Alteração de estado de forma inconsistente? Estou lhe perguntando isso, pois assim como a resposta do @RBZ acredito que analogia seja a melhor opção para fazer com que o problema seja compreendido, só acho que os exemplos de analogia dele não representam o real problema (que acredito que seja algo com concorrência ou estado). Precisamos de uma analogia melhor.

Comment: Downvoter, como posso melhorar a questão? Você não a marcou para fechamento, então entendo que você entendeu minha pergunta e que a considerou dentro do escopo, então interpretei seu voto como falta de qualidade. Estou disposto para tentar melhorar meu texto

Comment: @FernandoLeal, nem todo heisenbug vem de paralelismo. Peguei um hoje mesmo que estava relacionado a uma coincidência de valores, e dependendo da minha ação ao investigar, o bug deixava de ocorrer. E, pela característica de ser um heisenbug, eu não sei o que é que está ocorrendo; não posso ter certeza pois toda observação feita muda o estado do sistema a ponto de não reproduzir aquele bug específico

Comment: Downvoter, poderia explicar o porquê de votar negativo? Já que você não marcou para fechar a questão, creio que tenha julgado que ela esteja com algum problema, mas que ainda assim seja bem vinda no site

Answer (score 26):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa de uma **analogia**, assim facilitar **explicar algo complexo, para um leigo em programação (seu chefe)**.

Então tentarei explicar com minhas palavras o seu problema, se meu chefe fosse leigo.

### ***Analogia 1 - Ônibus quebrado***

**Fato**

Sou dono de uma empresa de Transporte coletivo.

**Problema**

Tenho um ônibus que sempre quebra o amortecedor.

**Debug**

O motorista de ônibus sempre percorre exatamente o mesmo percurso.

Com isso, irei junto a ele, e assim verificar o que está havendo.

Mas "incrivelmente" as vezes que fui junto, o ônibus não quebrou! Por quê?

**Solução**

Após suspeitas, foi acompanhado o problema de forma não tão invasiva, colocando um "espião" disfarçado de passageiro, e bingo!

Existe um buraco enorme em uma das ruas do trajeto, e o motorista nem sequer desvia deste buraco, a não ser, que esteja sendo **observado**.

**Resumindo**

Só o fato de estar **sendo observado**, resultou na **correção temporária** do problema.

---

### ***Analogia 2 - Cadê meu bife?***

**Fato**

Trabalho na empresa XYZ e sempre **levo marmita para o almoço**, onde deixo na geladeira comunitária que tem no serviço.

**Problema**

Como eu faço o 2º horário de almoço, **todo dia está "sumindo" um bife** da minha marmita.

**Debug**

Devido ao problema, comecei a **passar pelo refeitório no primeiro horário de almoço**. E assim, meu bife parou de "sumir". Por quê ?

**Solução**

Havia um funcionário, que ao ir buscar a própria marmita, abria outras marmitas e pegava os bifes (fator fora de sua "instrução" correta). Isso foi descoberto, **observando e analisando** todos os "recursos" (funcionários), até chegar no recurso causador do problema, onde o mesmo, visualmente **não estava ligado diretamente ao problema**, mas com um **fator de "intervenção"** (eu) alterava o resultado final.

Neste caso tem-se **3 soluções**:

- **Mandar o funcionário embora** (eliminar o recurso/processo)
- **Colocar câmeras** (criar recurso complementar que filtra a falha)
- **Aplicar advertência** (correção, com possibilidade de solução temporária)

**Resumindo**

Idem a Analogia 1, com exemplo de 3 possíveis soluções mais concretas.

---

### ***Analogia 3 - Entra e Sai do Fusca (fato verídico)***

**Fato**

Tenho um Fusca 1947!

**Problema**

Às vezes quando estou andando de Fusca, **ele para de funcionar de repente**. Encosto e tento dar partida várias vezes, mas **de forma alguma funciona**.

**Debug**

Antigamente, se ouvia que, quando o Fusca desse esse problema, **você deveria sair do veículo por 2 minutos, entrar novamente, dar partida, e ele iria ligar**.

De fato, feito e comprovado!

**Solução**

Após entender melhor a parte mecânica (estrutural), foi descoberto que a "bobina" esquentava e fazia a parte elétrica parar.

O fato de entrar e sair do veículo e esperar 2 minutos, fazia com que ela esfriasse o suficiente para voltar a funcionar.

**Resumindo**

Mais um exemplo, de **um terceiro fator chave** que não era nem imaginável e notável, e quando tentávamos uma solução fora de lógica mas que funcionava paliativamente, acabávamos **"viciando" nosso raciocínio em um "ponto de partida" incorreto**.

Isso é um exemplo de algo que quando "ligado" temos o problema, e quando "desligado" quando "paramos" para ver, fica difícil encontrar o verdadeiro problema. É como se um problema "visível", dependesse de outro problema para acontecer.

Comment: Só discordei das soluções. Afinal, se as soluções fossem tão fáceis, o bug não seria lá um bug tão misterioso, confere? Imagina que a "solução" do bug seja mandar imprimir na saída padrão o estado da variável. Só que isso geraria um tanto de sincronização que acabaria por tornar um processo naturalmente paralelo em sequencial. Isso pode significar horas de processamento a mais no servidor. Seria como a solução da demissão do funcionário do caso 2, afinal roubar marmita não dá justa causa. Sem falar que se identificou ser isso, mas não necessariamente se viu quem foi.

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer com a impressão. Mas pela pergunta ser a "necessidade de explicar ao leigo", somente analogias vão exemplificar. Exatamente como disse, roubo de marmita não dá justa causa, então tiveram 2 opções. A questão na analogia trata que o problema (bug) muda ao ser observado (Heisenbug), e não a forma de correção. Mas vou pensar em uma terceira analogia, em que exemplifique os fatores próximos afetando o resultado (nestes casos, seriam as outras pessoas que viram ou ficaram sabendo que o motorista era descuidado ou quem era o ladrão de bife) ;]

Comment: Ok, seu exemplo do fusca me ganhou.

Answer (score 0):

Como é uma explicação para leigos, temos que ser o mais genéricos possíveis e tentar explicar o problema **adaptando a comunicação conforme o interlocutor**.

Isto é um desafio imenso na nossa área, pois é bem comum desenvolvedores terem dificuldade em explicar o que estão fazendo aos seus superiores ou clientes sem entrar em muitos detalhes técnicos. Imagina, então, um *Heisenbug*?

Os leigos em questão (chefe e suporte) podem ser pessoas com um nível de entendimento de lógica mais apurado. Se não forem, a [resposta do rbz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286840/4492) se encaixaria perfeitamente.

Minha ideia aqui é aproximar melhor esta resposta da parte técnica, sem exagerar.

## Explicação

Como uma resposta mais técnica depende do problema a ser solucionado, eu iria pelo caminho de identificar qual tipo de Heinsenbug estamos lidando e começar minha explicação para os mais leigos a partir daí.

Vou pegar o exemplo de Heisenbug que ocorreu mais vezes comigo: *[race condition](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_corrida)*. Na tentativa de sanar o problema, você pode explicar da seguinte maneira:

> Este erro está ocorrendo em um fluxo do sistema no qual ele está
>   aguardando uma informação mas, de vez em quando, esta informação não
>   chega.
>
> Estou com problemas para reproduzir o bug pois quando eu estou
>   analisando passo-a-passo a execução do código, na tentativa de
>   verificar a causa do bug, eu acabo criando o tempo necessário para
>   esta informação chegar e o bug não ocorrer. Assim, acabo tendo mais
>   dificuldades para reproduzir o problema e identificar a correção
>   adequada.
>
> Para ter uma ideia deste tempo do qual eu estou falando, o fluxo todo
>   no ambiente de produção é executado em poucos milisegundos, mas quando
>   eu estou analisando o código este tempo leva vários segundos.