# Como funciona Workflow com Pull Request

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Estou querendo trabalhar com `Pull Request` no Git, mas não entendi como funciona, eu sei quando contribuo para um projeto, tenho que fazer `Fork`, `Branch`, `Commit` e `Pull Request`, e ai o dono do Repositorio, analisa e aceita ou recusa. Ok, mas quando se trabalha em equipe, como funciona esse fluxo?

Ex: cada pessoa do time, precisa fazer um `fork` do projeto? Ai ele tem que commitar, criar `branch`, enviar um `pull` para o `fork` dele e só enviar o `pull request`?

Comment: Eu faço no mesmo repositório usando `pull request`, sem necessitar de `fork`, apenas branches separados

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Conseguiria me passar como você faz? Porque atualmente eu faço isso, mas mesmo criando um Branch, quando eu subo (ou outra pessoa sobe), apenas fica disponivel, não tem uma aprovação

Comment: Agora o gitlab está instável, não vou pegar os projetos OpenSource tão rapidamente.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Preciso só o passo a passo, e como funciona, eu ouvi dizer que preciso bloquear o branch master

Comment: Fonte primária: https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ ; cheat-sheet: https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/ ; comparação da Atlassian: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: minha resposta atendeu ao seu problema? Tá faltando alguma coisa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem alguns níveis para dar uma resposta que eu considere adequada a sua pergunta:

1. o que é o `pull request`?
2. quais os ganhos de se usar `pull request`?
3. costumamos ver isso em portais que trabalham sobre [git](/questions/tagged/git), como [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/), [GitHub](https://github.com/) e [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)... tem alguma relação com o git em si?

## O que é o `pull request`?

É um modo suave de você enviar código para o projeto. Ele só entrará mediante aprovação do mantenedor do repositório.

## Quais os ganhos de se usar `pull request`?

Todo código de um `pull request` sofre revisão antes de entrar. Isso já garante muita coisa. Vide [Lei de Linus (por Eric Raymond)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus's_Law):

> given enough eyeballs, all bugs are shallow

Em tradução livre:

> dados olhos o suficiente, todos os bugs são rasos

O que quer dizer a Lei de Linus? Que quanto mais gente revisando um pedaço de código, mais facilmente os bugs são encontrados. Em algum lugar existe uma métrica (talvez falsa ou tendenciosa) de que pelo menos 50% dos bugs poderiam ser detectados/evitados a nível de revisão de código; minha experiência profissional indica que é pelo menos 90% dos bugs (dos outros 10%, 9% se dividem em especificação ruim, [heisenbugs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285712/64969) e requisito de performance não estabelecido).

Além disso, esse *workflow* garante a separação do desenvolvimento da equipe, então cada programador pode fazer o seu trabalho isoladamente e só integrar no código no final. Isolar-se garante que você não precisa *sempre* corrigir o que quebrou de compatibilidade com os demais, só precisa fazer isso **no final**.

No GitLab, esse processo se chama de `merge request`, mas é exatamente a mesma finalidade.

### Exemplo usando `pull request`

Eis uma árvore de commits de uma única pessoa usando `pull request` consigo mesma:

[image: árvore de commits do tc-compiler-help]

> a propósito, estou trabalhando ainda neste `fork`, está ainda muito incipiente

Outro exemplo:

[image: árvore de commits do totalcross-functional-toolbox]

Um exemplo da árvore de commits do repositório privado da empresa:

[image: árvore de commits do projeto]

[image: árvore de commits do projeto]

Note que a pessoa trabalha em seu *branch*, isoladamente, e só então quando "termina o suficiente", abre o `pull request` e, então, o revisor aprova/critica o código alterado. Note que não há necessidade do histórico ser "linearizável", com precedência absoluta entre quaisquer dois commits.

## Tem alguma relação com o git em si?

Na real? Não, não tem a ver com o git. Tem a ver com distribuição do código fonte, filosofia bazar e revisão de código.

Sistemas de controle de versão distribuídos (DVCS) facilitam o `pull request`, mas não é necessário. Todo controle de versão que aceita *branches*, até mesmo o SVN em seu modo centralizado de existir, é adequado para se usar esse fluxo; basta ter uma ferramenta que facilite =D

A "filosofia bazar" é uma visão antagonista da "filosofia catedral", ambas extraídas do jeito Open Source de desenvolver. [Leia mais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cathedral_and_the_Bazaar), se for o caso [compre o livro](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+cathedral+and+the+bazaar&tbm=shop) escrito pelo Eric Raymond.

A "catedral" é o repositório sagrado: todos podem ver, mas apenas os santos podem alterar. Já no "bazar", qualquer um pega e altera, qualquer um lança sua versão e é dono de seu próprio código. E depois manda as contribuições para o outro repositório, onde o mantenedor pode aceitar ou não.

O modo bazar de ser estimula a se criar `forks` de projetos. E a contribuição `upstream`, do repositório filho para o repositório original, é uma das formas de `pull request`. Mas ela não é a única.

Outra forma é um intermediário entre bazar e catedral, muitas vezes mais adequada ao mundo empresarial. Todos trabalham no mesmo repositório, em branches distintos, e as contribuições são aceitas pelo mantenedor, para lançar a versão.

### Como trabalhar adequadamente com esse `pull request`?

Existem algumas formas. Depende de como você quer o ciclo de vida do seu projeto.

Se for um projeto muito ágil que não precisa se preocupar em estabilização, você terá um branch `master` central, de onde saem as versões finais, e branches de correção e funcionalidades novas. Esses branches nascem e desaguam no `master`. Esse fluxo normalmente chamam de `feature branch`.

O `gitflow` ([mais](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) [sobre](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) o [assunto](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)) prevê outro ciclo de vida:

- branch `master` para a versão estável
- branch `develop` para a versão de desenvolvimento
- processo de liberação, onde `develop -> master` acontece

No `master`, nascem as correções em quente (`hotfix`), e elas devem voltar pro `master` e serem propagadas no `develop`. Do `develop`, em fase de desenvolvimento, nascem as funcionalidades (`features`) e correções advindas dele mesmo (`bugfix`) e devem voltar apenas pro `develop`. No processo de liberação, é feito um congelamento (`freeze`) do `develop` em um branch de `release`. Quando esse branch é estabilizado, ele deve ser mergeado no `master` e propagado no `develop`.