# Obter somente a parte decimal de um double

Tags: java, double

Preciso que retorne o valor arredondado.

```
exemplo: 576.43
saída: 43
```

O erro está sendo esse:

```
entrada: 576.43
saída: 42
```

Já tentei usar `df.format`, mas não deu certo.

Meu código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Entrada" );
        double n = sc.nextDouble();
        int noteBank = (int) n;
        int coins = (int) ((n - noteBank) * 100);        
        //apos a virgula
        System.out.println("Saida " + coins);
  }
}
```

Em algum momento o valor fica `0.429999`, mas continuo sem saber a melhor solução.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A raiz do problema está explicada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/112052). Basicamente, números de ponto flutuante (`float`/`double`) possuem uma imprecisão decorrente da forma como eles são representados (leia o link indicado, lá explica tudo em detalhes - apesar da pergunta ser sobre JavaScript, não importa, o problema é o mesmo em todas as linguagens que seguem o [padrão IEEE 754](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/112052)).

Só para ilustrar, vamos ver o que acontece no seu código:

```java
double n = 576.43;
int noteBank = (int) n;
System.out.println(noteBank); // 576
System.out.println(n - noteBank); // 0.42999999999995
System.out.println((n - noteBank) * 100); //42.999999999995
System.out.println((int) ((n - noteBank) * 100)); // 42
```

Eu imprimi vários resultados intermediários para você ver o que acontece passo a passo. A saída é:

```
576
0.42999999999995
42.999999999995
42
```

Pois é, ao fazer `n - noteBank`, o resultado não é `0.43` e sim `0.42999999999995`. O motivo está explicado [no link já indicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/112052).

---

## E como resolver?

Depende, cada caso é um caso. Usar `Math.round`, como sugeriu [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/553706/112052), pode ou não funcionar (pode funcionar para este caso específico, mas não para outros).

Na verdade, para valores monetários (que *parece* ser o seu caso), `double` não é o mais indicado, justamente por ter este tipo de imprecisão.

Geralmente recomenda-se multiplicar por 100 e usar `int` ou `long`, assim você trabalha com valores inteiros que correspondem à quantidade de centavos. Mas neste caso não serve, porque ao multiplicar por 100 você cai no mesmo problema (faça `System.out.println(n * 100);` e veja que o valor impresso é `57642.99999999999`, então qualquer cálculo feito com ele continuará errado).

Uma alternativa é ler os dados como `String` e convertê-la para um [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html), que é uma classe que não tem os problemas de imprecisão do `double` (converter para `double` não resolve, pois `Double.parseDouble("576.43")` cairia no mesmo problema). Mas tem o seu porém: `BigDecimal` tem um [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/112052) de memória e as operações são mais lentas do que com um `double`, mas é o preço a se pagar para não ter os problemas de precisão (não adianta, em computação tudo é um *trade-off*).

Então ficaria assim:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
// converte a String para BigDecimal
int valorEmCentavos = new BigDecimal(sc.nextLine()) // digitei 576.43
        // multiplica por 100 para ter a quantidade de centavos
        .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))
        // obtém o valor como um int
        .intValue();
System.out.println(valorEmCentavos); // 57643
int coins = valorEmCentavos % 100;
System.out.println(coins); // 43
int valorSemCoins = valorEmCentavos / 100;
System.out.println(valorSemCoins); // 576
```

---

A solução acima não funciona para números negativos (o valor de `coins` fica igual a `-43`). Você pode até fazer um `if` e inverter o sinal, mas também é possível fazer assim:

```java
BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal(sc.nextLine()) // digitei 576.43
int coins = valor.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE) // pega só a parte decimal
        .movePointRight(valor.scale()) // move o ponto duas casas para a direita
        .abs() // retirar o sinal
        .intValue(); // converte para int
System.out.println(coins); // 43
int valorSemCoins = valor.intValue(); // pega a parte inteira do número
System.out.println(valorSemCoins); // 576
```

Agora, `coins` sempre é positivo (se o valor digitado for `-576.43`, o valor de `coins` será `43`), mas o `valorSemCoins` mantém o sinal do valor original.

---

Por fim, tem outro porém. Se for digitado por exemplo `576.4` ou `576.456` ou ainda `576.400000`, o resultado ficará errado (`coins` será respectivamente `4`, `456` e `400000`). Então você pode forçar para que o valor sempre tenha duas casas decimais:

```java
BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal(sc.nextLine())
    // ter sempre duas casas decimais
    .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Você só precisa se atentar para o `RoundingMode`, que define a forma de arredondamento. No exemplo acima eu usei `HALF_UP`, que segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP) arredonda para o valor mais próximo, mas em casos de empate arredonda para cima. Ou seja, se digitar `576.455` ele arredonda para `576.46` (e o valor de `coins` será `46`), já `576.454` é arredondado para `576.45` (e o valor de `coins` será `45`). Consulte a documentação e veja todas as formas de arredondamento possíveis, e escolha a mais adequada para o seu caso.

---

Complementando, vale a leitura para se aprofundar no assunto:

- [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052)
- [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/112052)
- [Tipo Double e tipo Decimal, qual adequado para valor monetário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59010/112052)
- [Problema com centavos ao usar o tipo BigInteger](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118407/112052)
- [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/112052) (não é em Java, mas a ideia é a mesma)
- [Divisão matemática precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/112052) (em especial [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/112052), que tem vários outros links - alguns já estão acima, mas vale ler os demais)

Answer (score -2):

Não sei quais seriam as suas opções, mas acredito que você possa usar o `Math.round` para arredondar para cima.

Antes de mais nada mude o coins para `double`, pois ele que será usado pelo `Math.round`.

ex:

Caso só queira arredondar para cima se for número mais próximo do próximo:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class MeuPrimeiroPrograma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Olá, mundo");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Entrada" );
        double n = sc.nextDouble();
        int noteBank = (int) n;
        double coins = ((n - noteBank) * 100);        
        //apos a virgula
        System.out.println("Saida " + Math.round(coins));
    }
}
```

Comment: Continua não dando certo pois eu quero é armazenar o valor na variável,  dar o println com arredondamento eu já consegui , o difícil é armazenar o valor arredondado na variável,

Comment: Exemplo,  Double coins = Math.round(coins);

Comment: É possível Double X =10 *Math.round(coins); ?

Comment: Você pode usar double coins = Math.round((n - noteBank) * 100);

Comment: Também é possível usar double x =10 *Math.round(coins); como você mencionou

Comment: `round` não arredonda pra cima, e sim para o valor inteiro mais próximo. Por exemplo, `Math.round(2.5)` retorna `3` e `Math.round(2.2)` retorna `2` - se `round` arredondasse para cima, os dois casos retornariam `3`