# Validação em caixa eletrônico

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, validação

O usuário começa colocando um nome pra conta e o saldo inicial, aqui já tem um problema, quero que não seja possível digitar valores negativos nem números quebrados

Na opção depositar também quero fazer com que não se possa digitar números negativos nem números quebrados.

No saque preciso que não deixe digitar os números quebrados e negativos novamente, no saque se eu digitar um número negativo ele se soma com o saldo que possui na conta tipo: saquei -1 e tenho 10 de saldo, o saldo que se terá depois do saque e de 11.

Classe `Caixa`, onde digita o nome e o saldo inicial:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Caixa {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Declarando as variáveis, Scanner e Random
        String nome;
        double inicial;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random numero = new Random();
        int conta = 1 + numero.nextInt(9999);

        //Obtendo os dados iniciais do Cliente
        System.out.println("Cadastrando novo cliente.");
        System.out.print("Ente com seu nome: ");
        nome = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Entre com o valor inicial depositado na conta: ");
        inicial = entrada.nextDouble();

        //Criando a conta de um cliente
        Conta minhaConta = new Conta(nome, conta, inicial);
        minhaConta.iniciar();
    }


}
```

Classe `Conta`, realiza as ações de depositar, sacar e extrato:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conta {
    private String nome;
    private int conta, saques;
    private double saldo;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Conta(String nome, int conta, double saldo_inicial){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.conta=conta;
        saldo=saldo_inicial;
        saques=0;
    }

    public void extrato(){
        System.out.println("\tEXTRATO");
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
        System.out.println("Número da conta: " + this.conta);
        System.out.printf("Saldo atual: %.2f\n",this.saldo);
        System.out.println("Saques realizados hoje: " + this.saques + "\n");

    }

    public void sacar(double valor){
        if(saldo >= valor){
            saldo -= valor;
            saques++;
            System.out.println("Sacado: " + valor);
            System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente. Faça um depósito\n");
        }
    }

    public void depositar(double valor)
    {
        saldo += valor;
        System.out.println("Depositado: " + valor);
        System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
    }

    public void iniciar(){
        int opcao;

        do{
            exibeMenu();
            opcao = entrada.nextInt();
            escolheOpcao(opcao);
        }while(opcao!=4);
    }

    public void exibeMenu(){

        System.out.println("\t Escolha a opção desejada");
        System.out.println("1 - Consultar Extrato");
        System.out.println("2 - Sacar");
        System.out.println("3 - Depositar");
        System.out.println("4 - Sair\n");
        System.out.print("Opção: ");

    }

    public void escolheOpcao(int opcao){
        double valor;

        switch( opcao ){
            case 1:    
                    extrato();
                    break;
            case 2: 
                    if(saques<3){
                        System.out.print("Quanto deseja sacar: ");
                        valor = entrada.nextDouble();
                        sacar(valor);
                    } else{
                        System.out.println("Limite de saques diários atingidos.\n");
                    }
                    break;

            case 3:
                    System.out.print("Quanto deseja depositar: ");
                    valor = entrada.nextDouble();
                    depositar(valor);
                    break;

            case 4: 
                    System.out.println("Sistema encerrado.");
                    break;

            default:
                    System.out.println("Opção inválida");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só precisa adicionar mais uma verificação no seu método sacar, você precisa **verificar se o valor informado pelo cliente é menor que 0**

O ideal é fazer o mesmo para o depositar, os dois métodos vão ficar assim:

```
public void sacar(double valor){
    if(valor < 0){
      System.out.println("Não é possível sacar um valor negativo!\n");
    }
    else
    {
      if(saldo >= valor){
          saldo -= valor;
          saques++;
          System.out.println("Sacado: " + valor);
          System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
      } else {
          System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente. Faça um depósito\n");
      }
    }
}

public void depositar(double valor)
{
    if(valor < 0){
      System.out.println("Não é possível depositar um valor negativo!\n");
    }
    else
    {
      saldo += valor;
      System.out.println("Depositado: " + valor);
      System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pela *tag* quer que seja orientado a objeto, certo? Bem, o código está longe de ser OOP. Dei uma melhorada, mas ainda não é o ideal. E claro que resolvi o problema reportado na pergunta.

Mudei alguns textos e nomes para ficar mais dentro do contexto correto.

Tirei o randômico porque contas não possuem números aleatórios e sim sequenciais. É verdade que por este código só pode ter uma contas, então não faz diferença, mas se for mudado para ter várias contas já está pronto.

Tirei toda parte de tela da classe `Conta`. Isso é OO. Misturar responsabilidades não é. Provavelmente as operações de tela específicas deveriam estar em outra classe, mas não precisa em algo tão simples.

Eu poderia deixar fazer do jeito "errado", mas parece que quer aprender o certo.

A entrada de dados foi validada no básico conforme [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262981/101). Se não quer um valor com parte decimal, não use um tipo que permite decimal.

Se quiser usar um tipo com parte decimal, [não use o `double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101).

Me parece que a verificação se pode sacar, se o valor é aceito, como gerar o número da conta deve pertencer à `Conta`. Na verdade deveria ser até outro mecanismo, mas para um exercício não vale a pena de fazer algo mais complexo.

O correto seria usar `Enum` ou algo semelhante para comunicar o problema quando tenta a operação, mas estou com preguiça :) Tem que acha que deveria ser por exceção, tem essa cultura no Java, eu abomino exceções a não ser onde elas sejam o melhor mecanismo, o que não é o caso.

Não se esqueça que ainda tem vários erros menos óbvios no código, mas nada tão grave. Em código real em produção precisaria fazer bem mais que isso. Tem coisa que eu podia ter feito melhor, mas já estava cansando, isso deu canseira um um detalhe técnico.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Caixa {
    static private Conta minhaConta;
    static private Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opcao = -1;
        do {
            System.out.println("\t Escolha a opção desejada");
            if (minhaConta != null) {
                System.out.println("1 - Consultar Saldo");
                System.out.println("2 - Sacar");
                System.out.println("3 - Depositar");
            }
            System.out.println("4 - Abrir Conta");
            System.out.println("0 - Sair\n");
            System.out.print("Opção: ");
            opcao = lerInt();
            if (minhaConta == null && opcao != 0) opcao = 4;
            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("SALDO");
                System.out.println("Nome: " + minhaConta.getNome());
                System.out.println("Número da conta: " + minhaConta.getConta());
                System.out.printf("Saldo atual: %.2f\n", minhaConta.getSaldo());
                System.out.println("Saques realizados: " + minhaConta.getSaques() + "\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                if (minhaConta.podeSacar()) {
                    System.out.print("Quanto deseja sacar: ");
                    int ok = minhaConta.sacar(lerInt());
                    if (ok >= 0) {
                        System.out.println("Sacado: " + ok);
                        System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + minhaConta.getSaldo() + "\n");
                    } else if (ok == -1) System.out.println("Não pode ser negativo\n");
                    else if (ok == -2) System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente. Faça um depósito\n");
                     else if (ok == -3) System.out.println("Limite de saques atingidos.\n");
                } else System.out.println("Limite de saques atingidos.\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("Quanto deseja depositar: ");
                int ok = minhaConta.depositar(lerInt());
                if (ok >= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Depositado: " + ok);
                    System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + minhaConta.getSaldo() + "\n");
                } else System.out.print("Não pode ser negativo");
                break;
            case 4: 
                System.out.println("Cadastrando novo cliente.");
                System.out.print("Ente com seu nome: ");
                System.out.print("Entre com o valor inicial depositado na conta: ");
                minhaConta = new Conta(entrada.nextLine(), lerInt());
                break;
            case 0: break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opção inválida");
            }
        } while (opcao != 0);
    }
    private static int lerInt() {
        while (true) {
            String lido = entrada.nextLine().trim();
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(lido);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Desculpe, mas " + lido + " não é um número inteiro. Tente novamente.");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Conta {
    static private int ultimaConta;
    private String nome;
    private int conta, saques;
    private double saldo;
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public double getConta() { return conta; }
    public double getSaldo() { return saldo; }
    public int getSaques() { return saques; }
    public boolean podeSacar() { return saques < 3; }
    public Conta(String nome, int saldoInicial) {
        this.nome = nome;
        conta = ++ultimaConta;
        saldo = saldoInicial < 0 ? 0 : saldoInicial;
    }
    public int sacar(int valor) {
        if (valor < 1) return -1;
        if (saldo < valor) return -2;
        if (!podeSacar()) return -3;
        saldo -= valor;
        saques++;
        return valor;
    }
    public int depositar(int valor) {
        if (valor < 1) return -1;
        saldo += valor;
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ip8pUh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uagcutgv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/BankAccount.java).