# Tipo de dados não definidos em PHP

Tags: php

Pensando em um sistema de banco.

Se eu tenho uma variável $saldo; , eu posso jogar uma string dentro dessa variável em PHP.

Gostaria de saber como resolver esse problema em php.

e qual é a vantagem do php ter tipo de variável dinâmico.

Comment: Até onde eu saiba (trabalhei com PHP de meados de 2005 a 2012, depois tive pouco contanto, não sei das novidades, mas quanto a isso acho que não mudou nada) não é possível resolver o "problema" porque isso não é um "problema" e sim comportamento esperado da linguagem, caso você precise mesmo desse tipo de validação acredito que terá que optar por outra linguagem

Comment: como as pessoas fazem validação de formulários utilizando php? usa um java script algo do tipo? porque se não, não tem sentido algum(pra mim).

Comment: @NicolasGuilherme não compreendi muito bem o que vc quer, poderia ser mais especifico? Vc quer saber se uma variável é numérica?

Comment: No client-side você faz a validação por Javascript, porém você também tem que fazer a validação no PHP no server-side e tanto no JS como no PHP os tipos de dados são dinâmicos e isso não impede a validação. Se uma variável só pode conter números por exemplo basta fazer um cast no valor ou usar a função intval do PHP

Comment: Vantagem para bancos, nenhuma. Desvantagens, nenhuma. Basta saber usar, acredito que vc esteja com essa dificuldade porque usava algum ORM com uma linguagem fortemente tipada, mas PHP não trabalha nativamente assim, todavia existem frameworks para PHP que usam ORM, como Laravel, Cakephp, ou ORMs independentes como Propel e Doctrine. O controle dos tipos de dados deles é geralmente detectado automaticamente ou configurado pelo migrations ou um xml estruturado para eles.

Comment: @gato minha dúvida é a seguinte, se estou pedindo que o usuário digite o valor de $saque; , saque normalmente é do tipo float correto? quero restringir no php o tipo de dado, se eu simplesmente declarar a variavel $saque e pedir pro usuario inserir dados, ele por colocar o que ele quiser dentro dessa variável.

GuilhermeNascimento sou iniciante em programação, vim da linguagem JAVA (fortemente tipada).
Estou estudando a sintax da linguagem PHP, e parece ser bem complexa.

Comment: Em JSP se eu n me engano n precisaria disso tudo, pois você já define o tipo da variável na declaração, posso estar falando besteira pois sou iniciante, mas até entaum, é o que eu sei.

Comment: @NicolasGuilherme sim, mas ae nem é o JSP, era o Java, e isso não tinha relação com o banco, é que API para banco que fazia proveito disso. A sintaxe é simples, o problema é o que vc disse, as variaveis são dinamicas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não entendo nada de ORM/API, não sei o funcionamento delas ainda, não sei a relação com o banco que você quer dizer, infelizmente não sei sobre API Framework ORM etc, estou me esforçando para aprender a base da programação, depois estudar sobre o restante.
Mas, obrigado pelo esclarecimento,

Comment: @NicolasGuilherme qual sistema de ORM usava no Java? O problema é que cada ORM no PHP funciona de uma maneira, não existe um padrão certo, cada um tem o seu (apesar de todos serem vagamente semelhantes)

Comment: Respondendo a pergunta de como é feita a validação, isso fica a cargo do programador (no caso você) fazer as devidas validações, se você só espera números, você deve validar se o usuário só informou número, entende ? Usando cast's, funções nativas e até mesmo expressões regulares (RegEx) para validar e verificar se o que foi informado é o que era esperado (Quantos Guilhermes, até me confundi kkk)

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você está querendo ter tipagem estática numa linguagem dinâmica? Não é o caminho, embora tem gente que tente gambiarras. Ou trabalha da maneira como o PHP funciona, ou usa outra linguagem. Detalhe: qualquer dado que o usuário enviar via POST ou GET chega no servidor como string. Dali pra frente cabe a você validar e converter para outro tipo se necessário.

Comment: E antes de mais nada, seja em Java ou PHP, se está usando float pra $saque e $saldo, precisa aprender coisa mais básica do que enforce de tipo. Precisa antes saber escolher o tipo correto. Float para valores monetários (ou qualquer outra coisa que seja valor exato) é um defeito grave no código.

Comment: @Bacco qual seria o tipo usado para valores monetários?

na linha abaixo de saque, qual tipo eu colocaria?

quero sacar  R$ 11,50

Comment: @NicolasGuilherme ou usa ( centavos * 100 ) e guarda em INT, ou se a linguagem tiver, algum tipo específico para moeda (decimal, money). Float nunca. Float não é valor exato. A grosso modo, num float 5 + 5 pode ser 9.99997 em vez de 10, o que é um desastre para operações monetárias. Veja mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5746/70 - independente da linguagem, a razão é a mesma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP é dinâmico, mas mesmo que não fosse, isso de fato não define o que vai entrar no banco.

No PHP é possível controlar os dados de entrada, fora que os dados que vem do banco tem com o tipo do valor "aproximado" ao mesmo do banco (exceto alguns que viram string, por exemplo `BIGINT` e `DECIMAL`), ou quando o PHP é 32bit e o mysql 64bit (o que afeta alguns "limites"), isso pode depender da API que usa (mysqli ou pdo), não estou certo.

Por exemplo se fizer isso, lendo dados:

```
<?php
//Conecta
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

//Verifica se houve erros
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit;
}

//Query
$query = "SELECT id, nome, preco FROM Tabela LIMIT 1";

//Executa query
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* Pega os dados */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        //Exibe na tela, semelhante ao Symtem.out.println
        var_dump($row);
    }

    /* limpa resultados */
    $result->free();
}

/* fecha conexão */
$mysqli->close();
```

Ele retorna algo como isto:

> ```
> array(3) {
>   ["id"]=> int(1)
>   ["nome"]=> string(8) "carrinho"
>   ["preco"]=> string(6) "100.02"
> }
> ```

- `id` é `INT` e retornou um tipo `int`
- `nome` é `VARCHAR` e retornou `string`
- `preco` é `DECIMAL` e retornou `string`

> No caso provavelmente DECIMAL vira string porque se virasse `float` poderia perder a precisão dos dados, o que seria uma grande dor de cabeça

Veja que mesmo sem a tipagem o valor é de um tipo especifico no caso do ID ainda é INT (como disse não estou certo da situação para diferentes processadores e APIs)

Todavia é possível passar dados para query de maneira que verifique os dados de entrada:

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Tabela VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isd', $id, $nome, $valor);

$id    = 2;
$nome  = 'Boneca';
$valor = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d linhas inseridas\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Veja:

- **i** corresponde a uma variável de tipo `int`
- **d** corresponde a uma variável de tipo `double`
- **s** corresponde a uma variável de tipo `string`
- **b** corresponde a uma variável que contém dados para um blob e enviará em pacotes

Se bem que se tratando de `DECIMAL`, seria melhor passar string mesmo.

> **!!!** Recomendo que leia isso: [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/3635) **!!!**

### Concluindo

O próprio mysql de certa forma faz o "CAST" quando trabalha uma coluna de um tipo especifico, isso é independente de qualquer linguagem, então se a linguagem é dinâmica ou não é irrelevante de certa forma no final.

### ORMs populares e afins

Isso é apenas um adendo, existem vários ORMs em PHP, como [Propel](http://propelorm.org), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org) e frameworks que possuem seus próprios sistemas de ORM, por exemplo o [Laravel](https://laravel.com), ele através do `Migrations` pode controlar os tipos de [valores das colunas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns)