# Qual o melhor tipo no SQL para usar com CryptoCurrency?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde irei armazenar transações de CryptoCurrencies, tipo Bitcoin, não posso de maneira alguma ter problemas de conversão e arredondamento, no C# verifiquei e a melhor é `decimal`, certo ?

Os valores serão nesse formato:

> 0,000001

Sei que money no SQL Server não é uma boa opção, devo ir para um `decimal (x,x)`?

Poderei utilizar banco SQL Server ou MySQL, por isso coloquei a tag dos dois aqui, pois ainda está sendo decidido

Comment: Basicamente o que você quer é saber qual é o melhor tipo no banco de dados para se representar valores monetários com muitas casas decimais após a vírgula, é isso? Se for, o fato de ser bitcoin ou qualquer outra coisa, torna-se irrelevante.

Comment: Exato, usei o exemplo do bitcoin pela quantidade de casas decimais, que normalmente com transações monetárias normais (acho eu) não tem tantas casas assim.

Comment: @JoséDiz obrigado, talvez me expressei mal falando do tipo money, mas não é uma boa prática, sempre vejo o pessoal falando para NÃO usar de forma alguma.. saberia no mySQL se o decimal aplica da mesma forma? obg.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5746/melhor-tipo-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-dinheiro?rq=1)

Comment: @vnbrs eu pesquisei sobre o tipo para trabalhar com dinheiro, mas minha dúvida nesse tópico citado não tinha certeza se atenderia a quantidade de casas decimais e precisão necessária para a minha necessidade, gerando dúvida.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5746/melhor-tipo-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-dinheiro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para armazenar valores monetários deve-se evitar o tipo de dados `float` ([vírgula flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%ADrgula_flutuante)). Isto vale para qualquer linguagem. Quanto ao tipo de dados `money`, funciona corretamente, com 4 casas decimais fixas.

Pelo exemplo você necessita de 6 casas decimais, o que elimina o uso do tipo de dados `money`. No SQL Server pode utilizar decimal (*p*, *s*), onde *p* é a precisão e *s* é a escala. Ou seja, utilize 6 como escala. Para definir a precisão, atento que é necessário contabilizar tanto a parte inteira quanto a parte fracionária. Por exemplo, para armazenar valores até 9.999,999.999 são 4 algarismos na parte inteira e 6 algarismos na parte fracionária. Logo, a precisão deve ser
      `4 + 6 = 10`
Ou seja, `decimal (10, 6)`.

Quanto ao MySQL, há algum tempo que não o utilizo, exceto para testes esporádicos. Mas, consultando a documentação, é a mesma regra do SQL Server quanto a definição de precisão e de escala.

Documentação:

- [decimal e numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187746(v=sql.120).aspx)  (SQL Server)
- [money e smallmoney](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179882(v=sql.120).aspx)  (SQL Server)
- [DECIMAL, NUMERIC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html)  (MySQL)
- [DECIMAL Data Type Characteristics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)  (MySQL)
- [Decimal](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/decimal/)  (mariaDB)

---

Leia também:

- [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5746/melhor-tipo-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-dinheiro?rq=1)