# Regex para valores monetários

Tags: python, regex

Gostaria de saber como faço um regex para capturar um valor monetário com pontos e vírgulas. Ex: `7.300.250,00`

Comment: Que linguagem está usando?

Comment: Estou usando python

Comment: Vc quer só validar o formato ou quer também obter o valor numérico?

Comment: desejo obter o valor também

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para **validar** se a string está neste formato, você pode usar `^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$`:

- `^` e `$` são [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) para o início e fim da string. Assim você garante que a string só vai ter o que está especificado na regex
- `[1-9]` é uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Os colchetes indicam que você quer qualquer coisa que esteja dentro deles. No caso, `1-9` é "qualquer dígito de 1 a 9"
- `\d` é um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para `[0-9]` (dígitos de 0 a 9) e `{0,2}` é um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) que significa "entre zero e duas ocorrências"

  - portanto `[1-9]\d{0,2}` quer dizer que eu tenho um dígito de 1 a 9, seguido de zero, um ou dois dígitos de 0 a 9. Isso garante que a string não começa com zero

Em seguida, temos `(\.\d{3})*`:

- `\.` significa o caractere ponto (`.`). O ponto tem significado especial em regex (significa "qualquer caractere"), mas com a `\` antes, ele "perde seus poderes" e vira um caractere comum.
- `\d{3}` são 3 ocorrências de qualquer dígito de 0 a 9

  - a sequência "ponto seguido de 3 dígitos" está entre parênteses e em seguida temos o `*`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Isso quer dizer que podemos ter várias ocorrências (ou nenhuma) de "ponto seguido de 3 dígitos" (isso serve para verificarmos a sequência `.300.250` da sua entrada). O `*` também verifica se há zero ocorrências, o que é útil para valores menores que 1000.
- por fim, temos a vírgula seguida de 2 dígitos (`,\d{2}`)

Isso garante que a entrada estará no formato desejado. Veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/u7s8Qm/2/) a regex funcionando.

---

Mas isso só valida se a string toda corresponde ao valor monetário. Se quiser extrair tais valores de um texto, basta modificar um pouco:

```
import re

texto = "lorem ipsum 7.300.250,00 blabla 123 etc 1.234,12 blabla 45"
print(re.findall(r"[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}", texto)) # ['7.300.250,00', '1.234,12']
```

Retirei o `^` e `$`, assim ele busca em qualquer parte do texto. E usando `findall`, ele retorna uma lista com todas as ocorrências. Só lembrando que os parênteses formam um grupo de captura, e neste caso `findall` retornaria somente os grupos, por isso tive que modificar para um grupo de não-captura, adicionando `?:` depois do `(`.

---

Para **obter** o valor numérico, você pode simplesmente remover tudo que não for dígito e converter para `int`. Para isso, usamos a regex `\D` (que é o oposto de `\d`, ou seja, é tudo que não for dígitos de 0 a 9).

Com isso você terá a quantidade total de **centavos**. Abaixo eu transformo o valor para `int`, já que é [melhor usar tipos inteiros para trabalhar com valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052). Se quiser o valor sem os centavos, basta dividir por 100, e se quiser o valor dos centavos, use o operador `%`:

```
import re

s = "7.300.250,00"
# se está no formato desejado
if re.match(r"^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$", s):
    # retira tudo que não for dígito e converte para int
    valor = int(re.sub(r"\D", "", s))
    print("Valor (quantidade total de centavos): {}".format(valor))
    print("Valor sem os centavos: {}".format(valor // 100))
    print("Valor dos centavos: {}".format(valor % 100))
```

A saída é:

> Valor (quantidade total de centavos): 730025000
> Valor sem os centavos: 7300250
> Valor dos centavos: 0

---

Apenas um detalhe sobre o `\d`: ele também pode corresponder a [outros caracteres que representam dígitos](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), como por exemplo os caracteres `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` (veja [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230) para mais detalhes).

Exemplo:

```
s = "1٩,10"
if re.match(r"^[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$", s):
    valor = int(re.sub(r"\D", "", s))
    print("Valor (quantidade total de centavos): {}".format(valor))
```

Eu usei o caractere `٩` ([arabic-indic digit nine](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0669/index.htm)), que apesar de parecer com o dígito `9`, é um outro caractere. A saída é:

> Valor (quantidade total de centavos): 1910

Isso porque o `\d` também pega este caractere. Se quiser que somente os dígitos de `0` a `9` sejam considerados, troque `\d` por `[0-9]`:

```
if re.match(r"^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]{2}$", s):
    ... o resto é igual
```

---

Outro detalhe é que a regex só funciona para valores maiores que 1,00. Se quiser considerar também valores como 0,15 (15 centavos), tem que incluir uma condição para considerar somente um zero antes da vírgula:

```
if re.match(r"^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*),\d{2}$", s):
    ... o resto é igual
```

Agora eu uso [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou") para indicar que antes da vírgula pode ter somente um zero, ou toda a expressão que já vimos anteriormente).

Comment: Obrigado!! Muito completo e esclarecedor

Comment: Testei essa expressão no regex101 e não deu match com valores inferiores a 1 real (Ex: 0,50)

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos É, acabei esquecendo deste caso. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Caracas, que resposta rápida haha... Deu certo aqui ! Brigadão !

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar essa expressão:

```
 ^(([1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{3})*)|(([1-9]\.\d*)?\d))(\,\d\d)?
```