# Como pegar os ultimos numeros com REGEX?

Tags: regex

eu preciso pegar o valor do CSLL, q no caso é 458,33. Eu tentei de todas as maneiras capturar ele antes da palavra "VALOR" mas não deu certo. segue o texto:

IRRF    PIS/PASEP   COFINS  CSLL
0,00    297,92  1.375,00    458,33
VALOR TOTAL DA NOTA 45.833,17

Comment: Se já tentou de várias maneiras, por favor clique em [edit] e coloque as tentativas. Seria bom também dizer a linguagem ou ferramenta usada, pois cada uma implementa regex de um jeito e o que funciona para uma não necessariamente vai servir para outra. De qualquer forma, segue um exemplo que pode ser adaptado pro seu caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342855/112052