# Arredondamento no SQL

Tags: oracle, arredondamento

Preciso realizar um arredondamento de um resultado. No Oracle está assim:

```
SALDO_TONELADA = (A.PESO * 20,0);
```

O valor da coluna `A.PESO` é de `24.432` e multiplicado por 20 dá `488.640`.

O meu objetivo era receber um valor apenas de `488`, sem o ponto e sem valores após o ponto.

Já tentei utilizar o `ROUND` mas não resolveu meu problema.

Sei que no Excel tem uma fórmula que formata um determinado campo assim:

```
=esquerda(488.640; 3)
```

E como resposta teria `488`.

Sabem me dizer se no Oracle existe algo para formatar o campo para trazer apenas x caracteres?

Não sei se ficou claro, mas preciso que o resultado seja com 2 ou 3 caracteres para corrigir o cálculo de outras colunas que dependem deste resultado.

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101

Comment: Não tem um exemplo pra testar e não diz o que seria "não foi o suficiente". Fica difícil te ajudar

Comment: Este exemplo eu não tenho , ainda estou desenvolvendo dentro da aplicação .. basicamente, preciso multiplicar um resultado de peso para valor. e como resposta preciso que este valor tenha apenas 3 caracteres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível truncar os números após o ponto decimal com a função [TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm) porém se o valor for até 488.999 o resultado será 488.

A query seria:

```
TRUNC((A.PESO * 20),0)
```

Veja exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b76e4/9

Se quiser arredondar mesmo o valor correto seria 489 conforme regra matemática, nesse caso seria a função [ROUND](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm):

```
ROUND(A.PESO * 20)
```

Exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b76e4/4

Comment: Obrigado @Laércio Lopes, vou testar aqui ...

Comment: Se resolver seu problema aceite a resposta conforme imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg

Comment: para utilizar no MySQL o TRUNC não funfa, sabe qual que posso subistituir ?

Comment: No MySQL deve ser `TRUNCATE`, Corrigi o argumento da função que deve ser `0`.

Comment: Boa, obrigado !