# Dúvida iniciante Java - Por que o resultado da variável double está errado?

Tags: java, variáveis, int, double

Fiz um algoritmo que simula uma conta bancária, onde o cliente pode sacar e depositar valores, funcionou perfeitamente quando usei variáveis do tipo `int`, mas quando uso variáveis do tipo double (no intuito do algoritmo fazer contas com centavos) ele retorna alguns valores que julgo estar errado, por exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double valor1 = 10;
    double valor2 = 9.8;
    double resultado = valor1 - valor2;

    System.out.println(resultado);
```

O valor que ele me retorna é `0.1999999999999993`, quando julgo que o correto seria 0.2

Comment: Leie está [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219774/110782) Vinicius

Comment: Uma variável de ponto flutuante, de acordo com a norma IEEE 754-2008, é inerentemente imprecisa. Se sua aplicação exige precisão então não utilize este tipo de dado. Só o utilize se sua aplicação puder conviver com aproximações dentro de uma margem de erro.

Comment: Que tipo de dado devo utilizar para um algoritmo que possa somar e subtrair números decimais de forma precisa? Por exemplo R$: 20,00 - R$ 19,90?

Comment: Vinicius, vc pode ler mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052).