# PHP somando e subtraindo errado

Tags: php, float

Estou com um problema muito estranho aqui.

É um código para fechamento de caixa, tenho o valor total de vendas, o usuário informa vendas no crédito, débito e dinheiro, caso a soma das 3 seja igual ao total de vendas ele deixa fechar o caixa.

O problema é que pro PHP 211.1 - 211.1 = -2.8421709430404E-14

[image: Print]

```
public function isValid($value, $context = null)
{
    foreach ($context as $key => $valor) {
        $valor = str_replace('.', '', $valor);
        $valor = str_replace(',', '.', $valor);
        $context[$key] = (float)number_format($valor, 2);
    }

    $total = $context['total_pedidos'] - ($context['valor_credito'] + $context['valor_debito'] + $context['valor_dinheiro']);

    var_dump($context);
    var_dump($total);
    die();
    $this->setValue($total);
    if(empty($total)){
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->error(self::FLOAT);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Outra coisa, como eu usei o `number_format($valor, 2)` ele deveria colocar 2 casas decimais não?

Quando jogo outros valores ele faz a conta correto.

Estou usando o PHP 5.5.12

Comment: Ler também [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/5878)

Comment: E também [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/5878)

Answer (score 1):

O problema em si é a operação com números de ponto flutuante. Eles não são um valor exato, mas sim uma aproximação. Isso ocorre também em qualquer linguagem, não só no PHP. Por exemplo no JavaScritpt:

```js
a = 31.8;
b = 49.9;
c = 129.4;

total = 211.1;

alert(total - (a + b + c));
```

Temos aqui uma pergunta relacionada com esse assunto e com ótimas respostas (recomendo a leitura para um melhor entendimento):

[Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642/resultado-impreciso-em-c%c3%a1lculo-com-n%c3%bameros-quebrados)

Para resolver seu problema, você pode usar as funções de [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) para fazer cálculos matemáticos com pontos flutuantes de forma precisa:

```
<?php

$a = '31.8';
$b = '49.9';
$c = '129.4';

$total = '211.1';

bcscale(2);

$subtotal = bcadd($a, $b);
$subtotal = bcadd($subtotal, $c);

var_dump(bcsub($total, $subtotal));
```

[Veja funcionando](https://3v4l.org/inKVo).

Ou então fazer essas operações utilizando números inteiros, multiplicando por 100 e no final dividindo tudo por 100:

```
<?php

$context = [
    'total_pedidos' => '211,10',
    'valor_credito' => '31,80',
    'valor_debito' => '49,90',
    'valor_dinheiro' => '129,40'
];

foreach ($context as $key => $valor) {
    $valor = str_replace('.', '', $valor);
    $valor = str_replace(',', '.', $valor);
    $context[$key] = number_format($valor, 2) * 100;
}

$total = $context['total_pedidos'] - ($context['valor_credito'] + $context['valor_debito'] + $context['valor_dinheiro']);
$total = $total / 100;

var_dump($total);
```

[Veja funcionando](https://3v4l.org/n5ukT).

Outras referências:

- [Números de ponto flutuante - Documentação do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php)
- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic<sup>en</sup>](https://floating-point-gui.de/)
- [Floating-point cheat sheet for PHP<sup>en</sup>](https://floating-point-gui.de/languages/php/)
- [Arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic for PHP 7<sup>en</sup>](http://php-decimal.io/#introduction)

Comment: Funcionou com numeros inteiros, obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

## Aviso:

Embora a questão esteja usando float para manipular moeda, nunca armazene ou manipular dinheiro usando float, pois podem ocorrer erros de arredondamento. Trabalhe com números inteiros internamente, em que o número inteiro representa o número total de centavos. Uma alternativa  é usar o módulo de matemática [BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.bc.php), que lida com números de precisão arbitrários com 100% de precisão.

---

Quanto a questão você esqueceu de formatar a saída e fez um cast para um valor já formatado.

```
<?php
function isValid($context = null)
{
    foreach ($context as $key => $valor) {
        $valor = str_replace('.', '', $valor);
        $valor = str_replace(',', '.', $valor);
        // Sem o cast (float) se o fizer você perde a formatação.
        $context[$key] = number_format($valor, 2);
    }

    // Faltou formatar o resultado
    $total = number_format(
               $context['total_pedidos'] - (
               $context['valor_credito'] + 
               $context['valor_debito'] + 
               $context['valor_dinheiro']), 2);

    var_dump($context);
    var_dump($total);


}

$arr = [
'total_pedidos' => '211,1',
'valor_credito' => '31,8',
'valor_debito'  => '49,9',
'valor_dinheiro'=> '129,4'
];

isValid($arr);
?>
```

Resultado:

```
array(4) {
  ["total_pedidos"]=>
  string(6) "211.10"
  ["valor_credito"]=>
  string(5) "31.80"
  ["valor_debito"]=>
  string(5) "49.90"
  ["valor_dinheiro"]=>
  string(6) "129.40"
}
string(4) "0.00"
```

[Link para o código.](https://repl.it/repls/HalfDelayedApplicationframework)