# Como transformar um valor monetário em reais em um núḿero float?

Tags: javascript, float, valor-monetário

Eu preciso transformar um número que está no formato `20.000,00` (com pontos em cada milhar) para um número do tipo `float`, como faço isso?

```js
 var value = $('#money').val()

 var currency = value.replace(",00", "")
 
 var money =   currency.replace(/[ ,.]/g, '');
```

Comment: Só uma observação - Float para dinheiro, em praticamente qualquer situação, é pésima idéia - [Sugestão de leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/70)

Comment: Como representar um decimal em JavaScript então?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez isso ajude:

```js
 var value = $('#money').val() // ex: 20.000,99
 var currency = value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove tudo que não é dígito, fica então 2000099
 var money =   parseFloat(currency)/100; // 20000.99
```

**NOTA:** Esse exemplo funciona para valores com duas casas decimais (o mais comum em moeda brasileira)

Comment: thank you, valeu

Comment: @Bacco você tem razão. Vou explicitar que o número deve estar formatado com duas casas decimais.

Comment: Melhorou, vou tirar o comment anterior para nao gerar confusao