# Por que ao arredondar a soma de dois números, o resultado é NaN?

Tags: javascript

Por que ao arredondar a soma dos dois valores abaixo retorna `NaN`?

```js
numero1 = '1,10';
numero1 = parseFloat(numero1.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2); // output: 1.10
numero2 = '2,20';
numero2 = parseFloat(numero2.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2); // output: 2.20
total = Math.round(numero1 + numero2); // output: NaN
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Não retornou NaN...

Comment: Se pressionar executar o resultado dá 3.

Comment: Provavelmente é algum problema relacionado ao ambiente em que você está executando o código.

Comment: Editada, desculpem, faltou código.

Comment: Depois que converte os dois números em string o operador `+` funciona como concatenador.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como já disseram as outras respostas, o problema ocorre porque [`toFixed` retorna uma string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Return_value), então `numero1` e `numero2` serão strings. E quando você usa o operador `+` em strings, [elas são concatenadas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) e o resultado é outra string.

No caso, após as chamadas de `toFixed`, `numero1` se torna a string `'1.10'` e `numero2` se torna `'2.20'`. E ao concatená-las, o resultado é a string `'1.102.20'`:

```js
let numero1 = '1,10';
numero1 = parseFloat(numero1.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);
let numero2 = '2,20';
numero2 = parseFloat(numero2.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);
console.log(numero1 + numero2); // 1.102.20
```

E essa string, quando passada para [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), resulta em `NaN`, já que ela não é um número válido (comportamento [descrito na especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math.round)). Mas apenas para deixar claro, ao contrário do que afirmou [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440414/112052), `Math.round` pode sim receber strings como parâmetro, **desde que elas representem números válidos**:

```js
console.log(Math.round('1.23')); // 1
console.log(Math.round('7.9')); // 8
console.log(Math.round('-1234')); // -1234
console.log(Math.round('3.02e4')); // 30200 (número em notação científica)
console.log(Math.round('0xff')); // 255 (número em hexadecimal)
console.log(Math.round('')); // 0 (OK, esse é um caso "estranho", string vazia não deveria ser um "número válido", mas o JS acha que é...)
console.log(Math.round('1.102.20')); // NaN
console.log(Math.round('123xyz')); // NaN
```

---

### Arredondar ou não, eis a questão

Dito isso, a solução correta depende de vários fatores. Pois tem um detalhe importante que deve ser levado em conta: o arredondamento. `toFixed`, além de limitar a quantidade de casas decimais, também arredonda o valor caso necessário. Exemplos:

```js
console.log(1.991.toFixed(2)); // '1.99'
console.log(2.999.toFixed(2)); // '3.00'

console.log(1.247.toFixed(2)); // '1.25'
console.log(1.244.toFixed(2)); // '1.24'
```

E no seu caso, parece que você quer primeiro arredondar os valores (limitando-os a 2 casas decimais com `toFixed`) e depois somá-los - e no final arredondar o resultado com `Math.round`. Ou seja, se `numero1` for `'1,247'` e `numero2` for `'1,245'`, o resultado será `3`:

```js
function arredonda(n) {
    n = parseFloat(n.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);
    // toFixed retorna uma string, então eu preciso converter para número de novo
    return parseFloat(n);
}

let numero1 = '1,247';
numero1 = arredonda(numero1);
let numero2 = '1,245';
numero2 = arredonda(numero2);
console.log(numero1); // 1.25
console.log(numero2); // 1.25
console.log(numero1 + numero2); // 2.5
console.log(Math.round(numero1 + numero2)); // 3
```

Mas e se eu não arredondasse os números, e só aplicasse `Math.round` no resultado final? Nesse caso o resultado seria `2`:

```js
function converte(n) {
    // não usa toFixed, retorna o número com todas as casas decimais
    return parseFloat(n.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
}

let numero1 = '1,247';
numero1 = converte(numero1);
let numero2 = '1,245';
numero2 = converte(numero2);
console.log(numero1); // 1.247
console.log(numero2); // 1.245
console.log(numero1 + numero2); // 2.492
console.log(Math.round(numero1 + numero2)); // 2
```

Outra opção seria pegar somente as duas primeiras casas decimais dos números (sem arredondar) e o resultado também seria `2`:

```js
function converte(n) {
    n = parseFloat(n.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    // em vez de toFixed, uso matemática para pegar somente as duas primeiras casas decimais
    return Math.floor(n * 100) / 100;
}
numero1 = '1,247';
numero1 = converte(numero1);
numero2 = '1,245';
numero2 = converte(numero2);
console.log(numero1); // 1.24
console.log(numero2); // 1.24
console.log(numero1 + numero2); // 2.48
console.log(Math.round(numero1 + numero2)); // 2
```

Ou seja, cabe a você decidir qual abordagem usar. Não ficou claro se todos os valores que você recebe sempre tem exatamente 2 casas depois da vírgula. Se for isso, então não há arredondamento a ser feito e você nem precisaria usar `toFixed(2)`. Bastaria usar a segunda opção acima, que só converte para número, sem arredondar nada. Mas se a quantidade de casas decimais varia e pode ser maior que 2, a escolha de uma das abordagens acima pode fazer toda a diferença no resultado final.

> *Aliás, o primeiro `replace` é desnecessário para estes casos, pois ele remove tudo que não é número nem vírgula. Mas como as strings de exemplo só tem números e uma vírgula, então esse `replace` não faz nada. Mas enfim, se os dados reais possuem outros caracteres, aí faz mais sentido usá-lo, senão poderia removê-lo sem problemas.*

---

### Dinheiro?

Por [este comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/440413/por-que-x-y-nan#comment849854_440414), dá a entender que você está trabalhando com valores monetários. Se realmente for isso, então o melhor é [não usar números de ponto flutuante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052) (leia mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/112052)). Em vez disso, você pode simplesmente remover a vírgula e trabalhar com a quantidade total de centavos. Depois, na hora de exibir o valor, aí você formata da maneira que achar melhor.

No caso de valores monetários, você pode inclusive usar [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) para formatar o valor de uma maneira mais "bonita":

```js
function converteParaCentavos(n) {
    // assumindo que o valor sempre tem 2 casas depois da vírgula,
    //basta remover tudo que nao é número para ter a quantidade de centavos
    return parseFloat(n.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, ''));
}

// converte tudo para centavos
numero1 = '1,24';
numero1 = converteParaCentavos(numero1);
numero2 = '1,24';
numero2 = converteParaCentavos(numero2);
console.log(numero1); // 124
console.log(numero2); // 124
console.log(numero1 + numero2); // 248

// somente na hora de mostrar, eu divido por 100 para mostrar o valor em reais
console.log(Math.round((numero1 + numero2) / 100)); // 2

// exemplo com Intl.NumberFormat
let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL',
});

// sem arredondar
console.log(formatter.format((numero1 + numero2) / 100)); // R$ 2,48
// arredondando
console.log(formatter.format(Math.round((numero1 + numero2) / 100))); // R$ 2,00
```

Comment: como mencionou, sim eu estou trabalhando com valor monetário, ficou clara sua resposta, deu tudo certo agora, foi uma aula tudo isso e sanou outras dúvidas que tinha, obrigado pela sua sapiência e boa vontade.

Answer (score 2):

O resultado `NaN` é devido a utilizado do `Math.round` em uma string.

Quando você utiliza o método `toFixed`, o retorno é uma string.

```js
numero1 = '1,10';
numero1 = parseFloat(numero1.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
numero2 = '2,20';
numero2 = parseFloat(numero2.replace(/[^0-9,]*/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
total = Math.round(numero1 + numero2);
console.log(total);
```

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Mas se numero1 = '10,99' e numero2 = '21,01', os centavos são "comidos";

Comment: Não tive esse problema: https://repl.it/repls/RecursiveTenderOutcome

Comment: cara, foi uma tremenda coincidência em ter um valor redondo, mas refazendo a pergunta, se for "1,11" e "1,13", o resultado seria "2.24", mas retorna número inteiro, como no seu exemplo, e não tem representação após o .(ponto).

Comment: @EliseuB. Retorna um número inteiro porque [esse é o retorno de `Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round). Se não quer que "coma" os centavos, não chame `Math.round`

Comment: @EliseuB. Outra coisa, se está lidando com valores monetários, é melhor não usar `float`, e também tem como formatar sempre com os centavos. Veja na parte final da [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440431/112052) :-)