# erro na porcentagem?

Tags: c

Um problema bem interessante, os dois primeiros `if` me retornam valores válidos, porém o último retorna um valor diferente do desejado. O que fazer?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    //declaracao de variaveis
    float salario;

    float final1; // 1 item
    float final2; // 2 item
    float final3; // 3 item

    //inicio
    printf("\nDigite o salario:R$ ");
    scanf("%f", &salario);

    if(salario<600.00)
        printf("\nIsento da taxa de contribuicao!");
    else
    if(salario > 600.00 || salario <=1200.00)
    {
        final1 = salario * 0.2;
        printf("\nA contribuicao sera de:R$ %2.f", final1);
    }

    else
    if(salario > 1200.00 || salario <= 2000.00)
    {
        final2 = salario * 0.25;
        printf("\nA contribuição sera de:R$ %2.f", final2);
    }

    else
    if(salario > 2000.00)
    {
        final3 = salario * 0.3;
        printf("\nA contribuição sera de:R$ %2.f", final3); 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua lógica da estrutura if está incorreta, mude todos os operadores OU (`||`) para  o operador E(`&&`):

Pois quando você insere, por exemplo, 700 reais para a variável salario ela satisfaz a condição do primeiro if: `salario > 600` e realiza a operação:  `final1 = salario * 0.2;` portanto para evitar isso modifique para o operador E (`&&`)

Seus laços if ficarão assim:

```
...
if(salario > 600.00 && salario <=1200.00)
....
if(salario > 600.00 && salario <=1200.00)
....
```

Comment: muito obrigado. erro devido a minha falta de atenção!

Comment: @JoãoRosa disponha! e veja a melhor forma de dizer obrigado no link: [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas) aconselho também a fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que sua condição `if(salario > 600.00 || salario <=1200.00)` está com um operador lógico de `OU`... Com isso, qualquer número superior a 600 vai cair nessa condição, nunca chegando nas demais condições.

---

Você pode corrigir isso, colocando nas suas condições o operador lógico `E`, em C representado por `&&`.

Corrigindo assim a condição em relação ao 600:

```
if(salario >= 600.00 && salario <=1200.00)
```

E também a em relação a 1200:

```
if(salario > 1200.00 && salario <= 2000.00)
```

---

Com isso, seu código ficara mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    //declaracao de variaveis
    float salario;

    float final1; // 1 item
    float final2; // 2 item
    float final3; // 3 item

    //inicio
    printf("\nDigite o salario:R$ ");
    scanf("%f", &salario);

    if(salario<600.00)
        printf("\nIsento da taxa de contribuicao!");
    else
        if(salario >= 600.00 && salario <=1200.00)
        {
            final1 = salario * 0.2;
            printf("\nA contribuicao sera de:R$ %2.f", final1);
        }
        else
            if(salario > 1200.00 && salario <= 2000.00)
            {
                final2 = salario * 0.25;
                printf("\nA contribuição sera de:R$ %2.f", final2);
            }

            else
                if(salario > 2000.00)
                {
                    final3 = salario * 0.3;
                    printf("\nA contribuição sera de:R$ %2.f", final3); 
                }
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/QuarrelsomeFreeSupercollider

---

Existe também um ponto em relação a sua impressão, você está omitindo as casas decimais com a máscara `%2.f`... Porém não sei se era o desejado, seu percentual sempre será exibido como um valor inteiro.

Answer (score 1):

As outras respostas explicaram o problema (usar `||` em vez de `&&`), mas na verdade você não precisa de duas condições nos `if`'s. Por exemplo, neste `if`:

```
if (salario < 600.00) {
    printf("\nIsento da taxa de contribuicao!");
} else ...
```

Se o salário for maior ou igual a 600, ele não entra no `if` e vai direto pro `else`. Então ao chegar no `else`, eu **já sei que naquele ponto o valor é >= 600** e testar essa condição de novo é redundante. Ou seja, poderia ser apenas:

```
if (salario < 600.00) {
    printf("\nIsento da taxa de contribuicao!");
} else if (salario <= 1200.00) { // aqui eu sei que é >= 600 e só preciso testar se é <= 1200
    ....
} else ...
```

A mesma coisa vale para o segundo `else`. Se chegou ali é porque o salário não é menor que 600, nem menor ou igual a 1200, ou seja, naquele ponto ele com certeza é maior que 1200 e não preciso testar isso de novo.

Usando essa mesma lógica para as demais condições, ficaria assim:

```
if (salario < 600.00) {
    printf("\nIsento da taxa de contribuicao!");
} else if (salario <= 1200.00) {
    printf("\nA contribuicao sera de:R$ %.2f", salario * 0.2);
} else if (salario <= 2000.00) {
    printf("\nA contribuição sera de:R$ %.2f", salario * 0.25);
} else {
    printf("\nA contribuição sera de:R$ %.2f", salario * 0.3); 
}
```

Repare que no último `else` nem precisa de condição, pois se chegou ali é porque o salário com certeza é maior que 2000 e não precisa testar de novo.

Repare também que, se você só quer imprimir o valor e nada mais, nem precisa das variáveis `final1`, `final2` e `final3`. Mudei o formato para `%.2f` porque do jeito que estava antes não mostrava as duas casas decimais (do jeito que fiz parece ser o que você quer, já que se trata de valores monetários).

Se bem que, se for trabalhar com valores monetários, [não use `float`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052) (para um exercício tanto faz, mas para aplicações sérias, não).

Comment: Entendi. desculpe a pergunta, mas qual seria a variavél recomendada para valores monetários?

Comment: @JoãoRosa Veja o link indicado acima ([esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052)). O melhor é usar `int` e guardar a quantidade de centavos, no link explica melhor os motivos. Tem também [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo legal não sabia deste tipo decimal, então `c#` em comparação ao `C` é mais indicado para valores monetários? ou, na linguagem c, usando `int` com os centavos armazenados realizaria perfeitamente a função do `decimal` ?

Comment: @LuizAugusto Em C acho que usar `int` é o suficiente (ou `long` dependendo dos valores que vc vai manipular), pois já evita os problemas de arredondamento e outras bizarrices do `float`