# Por que quando eu tento imprimir fora das condições, o compilador informa que minha variável não foi inicializada?

Tags: java

estou enfrentando o seguinte problema em Java:

- Quando tento executar a impressão das variáveis `nome, aumento e salario_ajustado` dentro das minhas condições, o código é compilado com sucesso e roda normalmente:

  ```
      public class Main
      {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

      double aumento, salario, salarioMinimo, salario_ajustado;

      System.out.printf("Nome do funcionário: ");
      String nome = input.nextLine();

      System.out.printf("Salário Atual: R$");
      salario = input.nextDouble();

      System.out.printf("Valor do salário mínimo: R$");
      salarioMinimo = input.nextDouble();

      if(salario/salarioMinimo<3)
      {
          aumento = salario*0.5;
          salario_ajustado = salario + aumento;
          System.out.println("Funcionário: " +nome);
          System.out.println("Ajuste de: R$" +aumento);
          System.out.println("Salario ajustado: R$" +salario_ajustado);
      }
      else if (salario/salarioMinimo>=3 && salario/salarioMinimo<=10)
      {
          aumento = salario*0.2; 
          salario_ajustado = salario + aumento;
          System.out.println("Funcionário: " +nome);
          System.out.println("Ajuste de: R$" +aumento);
          System.out.println("Salario ajustado: R$" +salario_ajustado);
      }
      else if (salario/salarioMinimo>10 && salario/salarioMinimo<=20)
      {
          aumento = salario*0.15; 
          salario_ajustado = salario + aumento;
          System.out.println("Funcionário: " +nome);
          System.out.println("Ajuste de: R$" +aumento);
          System.out.println("Salario ajustado: R$" +salario_ajustado);
      }
      else if (salario/salarioMinimo>20)
      {
          aumento = salario*0.1; 
          salario_ajustado = salario + aumento;
          System.out.println("Funcionário: " +nome);
          System.out.println("Ajuste de: R$" +aumento);
          System.out.println("Salario ajustado: R$" +salario_ajustado);
      }

  }
  ```

}```

mas quando tento executar essas mesmas impressões fora do meu condicionamento, o console apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
     *Main.java:38: error: variable aumento might not have been initialized
     System.out.println("Ajuste de: R$" +aumento);*
```

Segue o código com a impressão fora do condicionamento:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    double aumento, salario, salarioMinimo, salario_ajustado;
    
    System.out.printf("Nome do funcionário: ");
    String nome = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.printf("Salário Atual: R$");
    salario = input.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.printf("Valor do salário mínimo: R$");
    salarioMinimo = input.nextDouble();
    
    if(salario/salarioMinimo<3)
    {
        aumento = salario*0.5;
        salario_ajustado = salario + aumento;
    }
    else if (salario/salarioMinimo>=3 && salario/salarioMinimo<=10)
    {
        aumento = salario*0.2; 
    }
    else if (salario/salarioMinimo>10 && salario/salarioMinimo<=20)
    {
        aumento = salario*0.15; 
    }
    else if (salario/salarioMinimo>20)
    {
        aumento = salario*0.1; 
    }
    
        System.out.println("Funcionário: " +nome);
        System.out.println("Ajuste de: R$" +aumento);
        System.out.println("Salario ajustado: R$" +salario_ajustado);
    
}
```

}

**Lembrando que esse exercício é de uma lista iniciante e não há a necessidade de criar uma classe para executar a tarefa requisitada.**

Comment: No segundo código, o compilador acha que pode ter alguma situação em que ele não entra em nenhum `if`, e portanto a variável `aumento` não será inicializada. Basta remover o último, deixando apenas o `else`, pois se chegou ali é porque com certeza é maior que 20 e não precisa testar de novo. Aliás, poderia guardar o valor de `salario/salarioMinimo` em uma variável em vez de fazer o mesmo cálculo toda hora (aliás, acho curioso como muita gente não cria variáveis quando precisa e cria quando não precisa, mas divago...)

Comment: Aproveitando, tem como simplificar essas condições: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444359/112052

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No código a variável **aumento** é declarada mas sua inicialização só ocorre dentro dos blocos com **if**. O que está acontecendo é que se nenhuma das condições dos  **if**s forem satisfeitas a inicialização não acontece, se você modificar a linha (do último if):

```
else if (salario/salarioMinimo>20)
{
    aumento = salario*0.1; 
}
```

para:

```
else
{
    aumento = salario*0.1; 
}
```

o código irá funcionar.
O código pode ser melhorado um pouco se escrito da seguinte forma:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
double aumento, salario, salarioMinimo, salario_ajustado;

System.out.printf("Nome do funcionário: ");
String nome = input.nextLine();

System.out.printf("Salário Atual: R$");
salario = input.nextDouble();

System.out.printf("Valor do salário mínimo: R$");
salarioMinimo = input.nextDouble();

double indiceAumento = salario/salarioMinimo;
if(indiceAumento < 3)
{
    aumento = salario*0.5;
}
else if (indiceAumento >= 3 && indiceAumento <= 10)
{
    aumento = salario*0.2; 
}
else if (indiceAumento > 10 && indiceAumento <= 20)
{
    aumento = salario*0.15; 
}
else
{
    aumento = salario*0.1; 
}
salario_ajustado = salario + aumento;
System.out.println("Funcionário: " +nome);
System.out.println("Ajuste de: R$" +aumento);
System.out.println("Salario ajustado: R$" +salario_ajustado);   
}
```

Perceba que a variável salário ajustado também deve ser calculada fora dos ifs por que estava sendo calculada somente dentro do primeiro if, e se o código percorre qualquer outro caminho a variável salario_ajustado faria com que um erro ocorresse.