# Conversão de virgula para ponto java

Tags: java, string, conversão

Estou com dificuldades de conseguir fazer o meu `getPreco()` ficar formatado. A entrada do dado é por meio de um `textField`.

```
if (radioGuitar.isSelected()) {
  Guitarra guitarra = new Guitarra();
  guitarra.setMarca(txtMarca.getText());
  guitarra.setModelo(txtModelo.getText());

  if (btnRevisado.isSelected()) {
    guitarra.setPreco(150 + Double.parseDouble(txtPreco.getText()));
  } 

  else {
    guitarra.setPreco(Double.parseDouble(txtPreco.getText()));
  }
  
  guitarra.getPreco().toString().replaceAll(",", ".");
  
  System.out.println(guitarra.toString());
  
  bw.write(guitarra.getMarca());
  bw.write(separador);
  bw.write(guitarra.getModelo());
  bw.write(separador);
  bw.write(Double.toString(guitarra.getPreco()));
  bw.write(separador);
  bw.newLine();
  bw.close();
  fw.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para formatar valores monetários, uma boa alternativa é usar [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). Ex:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(123456.78)); // R$ 123.456,78
```

Eu uso um [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) (no exemplo acima usei `pt_BR`, que equivale ao português do Brasil), pois ele controla alguns aspectos da formatação, como os caracteres usados para separar os milhares e as casas decimais, além do prefixo "R$". Se você usar por exemplo `Locale.US` - inglês americano, o resultado será `$123,456.78` (e se chamar `getCurrencyInstance()` sem parâmetros, é usado o *locale default* que estiver configurado na JVM, por isso recomendo usar um *locale* específico para não depender dessas configurações, que inclusive podem mudar em *runtime* sem você perceber).

---

Com `NumberFormat` você pode controlar outros aspectos, como a opção de não incluir o ponto para separar os milhares, mudar a quantidade de casas decimais e até mesmo o modo de arredondamento. Alguns exemplos:

```
double valor = 123456.78987;
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

System.out.println(formatter.format(valor)); // R$ 123.456,79

formatter.setGroupingUsed(false); // não separar os milhares
System.out.println(formatter.format(valor)); // R$ 123456,79

formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN); // arredondar sempre para baixo
System.out.println(formatter.format(valor)); // R$ 123456,78

// mudar a quantidade de casas decimais
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
System.out.println(formatter.format(valor)); // R$ 123456,789
```

Consulte a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) para mais detalhes.

---

Se não quiser imprimir o símbolo da moeda e quiser somente formatar o número, aí bastaria usar `DecimalFormat`, como já sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/462396/112052). Ela também possui os mesmos métodos para controlar a quantidade de casas decimais, etc, mas por padrão não imprime o código da moeda (R$) - embora também seja possível:

```
// \u00A4 corresponde ao código da moeda
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("\u00A4 #,##0.00");
df.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("BRL")); // BRL = código do Real
System.out.println(df.format(valor)); // R$ 123.456,79
```

O código da moeda passado para [`Currency.getInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance-java.lang.String-) é baseado na [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217). No caso, usei `BRL`, que equivale ao Real.

Outro detalhe é que, se for trabalhar com valores monetários, talvez `double` não seja a melhor opção. Saiba mais lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/112052)

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, eu utilizo os seguintes métodos, o primeiro você define o número de casas decimais após a virgula, já o segundo é padrão:

```
public static String DoubleToString(double valor, int casasDecimais) throws ParseException{
    String retorno;
    String mascara = "#,##0.";
    if(casasDecimais < 0)
    {
        casasDecimais = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < casasDecimais; i++)
    {
        mascara += "0";
    }
    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat(mascara); 
    return df.format(valor);    
}

public static String DoubleToString(double valor) throws ParseException{
    String retorno;
    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"); 
    return df.format(valor);    
}
```